# Calculate average characters of string

Tags: code-golf, string

## Task

Your task is to produce string that contains average characters of string.
First character of result would be average character of first character (which is first character) and second character average of two first characters and so on.

## What is average character?

Strings are arrays of bytes. *Average character* of string can be found by calculating the average of the ASCII values of characters in string and taking corresponding ASCII character.

For example string `"Hello!"` can be written as byte sequence `72 101 108 108 111 33`. Average of ascii values is 533/6 = 88.833... and when it's rounded to nearest integer we get 89 which is ascii code for captial letter `Y`.

## Rules

- You can assume that input contains only printable ASCII characters
- Input can be read from stdin or as command line arguments or as function arguments
- Output must be stdout. If your program is function, you can also return the string you would otherwise print.
- It must be whole program or function, not snippet
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply
- Integers are rounded by function `floor(x+0.5)` or similar function.

## How do I win?

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer (in bytes) in wins.

## Examples

- `Hello!` → `HW^adY`
- `test` → `tmop`
- `42` → `43`
- `StackExchange` → `Sdccd_ccccddd`

Comment: Edited question. Now it should be clear: you have to round halves upwards.

Comment: "_Input can be read from stdin or as command line arguments_": or as function arguments (since you allow functions), right?

Comment: Of course, edited again.

Comment: Sorry to bother you once again, but do functions actually have to print the output to STDOUT or can they return the desired string?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to edit that before. Now it should be ok.

Comment: `StackExchange` should be Sdcce`ccddeee

Comment: Shouldn't `Hello!` be `HW^bdY`?

Comment: `Sdcce\`ccddeee` and `HW^bdY` bugs are if you use ceil instead of round, while `HV^adY` bugs is if you use banker's rounding (round to even). The original asker has it right for traditional math rounding.

Answer (score 14):

### Brainfuck 106 bytes

```
,[>,<.[->+<]>>++<[>[->+>+<<]>[-<<-[>]>>>[<[>>>-<<<[-]]>>]<<]>>>+<<[-<<+>>]<<<]>[-]>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<]
```

This is my first participation in a code-golf, please be gentle!
It does work but brainfuck can't handle floats (not that i know of) so the rounded value is always the bottom one (might fix my algorithm later).

Also, the algorithm averages the values 2 by 2, meaning it could be innacurate in some spots.
And I need to fix a bug that is printing a number at the end of the output too.

Answer (score 10):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
smCs+.5csaYCdlYz
```

Pretty straightforward. Using `s+.5` instead of rounding, because for some reason `round(0.5, 0)` is 0 in Python.

Comment: Python 3 rounds half towards even, which introduces less bias. The question doesn't explicitly specify how halves should be rounded, so I've requested clarification from the OP.

Comment: Edited question. `0.5` rounded should be `1`.

Answer (score 7):

## Q, <s>15</s> 12 bytes

12 bytes as an expression

```
"c"$avgs"i"$

q)"c"$avgs"i"$"Hello!"
"HW^adY"
q)"c"$avgs"i"$"test"
"tmop"
q)"c"$avgs"i"$"42"
"43"
q)"c"$avgs"i"$"StackExchange"
"Sdccd_ccccddd"
```

or 15 bytes as a function

```
{"c"$avgs"i"$x}

q){"c"$avgs"i"$x} "Hello!"
"HW^adY"
q){"c"$avgs"i"$x} "test"
"tmop"
q){"c"$avgs"i"$x} "42"
"43"
q){"c"$avgs"i"$x} "StackExchange"
"Sdccd_ccccddd"
```

takes advantage of

1. the "i"$ cast to convert a string (list of characters) to a list of integers
2. the avgs function, which computes the running average of a list as a list of floats
3. the "c"$ cast to convert a list of floats to a list of characters, and which  automatically rounds each float to the nearest integer before doing so [i.e. ("c"$99.5) = ("c"$100) and ("c"$99.4) = ("c"$99) ]

Comment: Does Q require the function wrapper here or can you get away with just the tacit expression `"c"$avgs"i"$` ? I don't think a solution could get much more straightforward than that. :)

Comment: you're correct --  no need for the function wrapper, as

"c"$avgs"i"$ "Hello!"

works fine

Comment: I think you can save 2 bytes by changing `"c"` to \`c and `"i"` to \`i.

Comment: unfortunately, i don't think that works. To use the symbol type representation for casting I'd have to use \`char and \`int as per http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/casting_and_enumerations#Cast_.28.24.29   I considered using 10h and 6h instead of "c" and "i" but that wouldn't save any bytes -- 10h is the same length as "c" and substituting 6h for "i" requires a trailing space, making them the same length also.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 19 bytes

```
Uq{i+_U):Ud/moco}/;
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=Uq%7Bi%2B_U)%3AUd%2Fmoco%7D%2F%3B&input=StackExchange).

Answer (score 4):

## Perl: <s>31</s> 30 characters

(29 characters code + 1 character command line option.)

```perl
s!.!chr.5+($s+=ord$&)/++$c!ge
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ perl -pe 's!.!chr.5+($s+=ord$&)/++$c!ge' <<< 'StackExchange'
Sdccd_ccccddd
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 65 bytes

```python
n=t=0
for c in input():n+=1;t+=ord(c);print(end=chr(int(.5+t/n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8@2xNaAKy2/SCFZITMPiApKSzQ0rfK0bQ2tS7Rt84tSNJI1rQuKMvNKNFLzUmyTM4o0QGw9U@0S/TxNTc3//z1Sc3LyFQE)

If I use `round()` instead of `int(.5+` etc., it saves one character but is *technically* not in compliance with the challenge: Python's `round()` rounds halves to the nearest even integer, not upwards. However, it works correctly on all sample inputs.

Comment: If you increment n before printing, you can avoid adjusting it by 1.

Comment: @xnor: Face, palm. Palm, face. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: do `print(end=chr(int(...))` to save some bytes

Comment: @Flp.Tkc: Thanks! Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

## C# <s>189 135 134</s> 106 Bytes

```
var x=s.Select((t,i)=>Math.Round(s.Select(a=>(int)a).Take(i+1).Average())).Aggregate("",(m,c)=>m+(char)c);
```

Can be seen [here](http://csharppad.com/gist/f6195bf7201b38ea8f3c)

First time golfer

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 46

```
s=0.0
$<.bytes{|b|s+=b;$><<'%c'%(0.5+s/$.+=1)}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/FmKAjX).

With apologies to w0lf, my answer ended up different enough that it seemed worth posting.

`$<.bytes` iterates over each byte in stdin, so we print the rolling average in each loop. '%c' converts a float to a character by rounding down and taking the ASCII, so all we have to do is add 0.5 to make it round properly. `$.` is a magic variable that starts off initialized to 0--it's supposed to store the line count, but since here we want byte count we just increment it manually.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 75 bytes

```js
let f =
s=>s.replace(/./g,x=>String.fromCharCode((t+=x.charCodeAt())/++i+.5),i=t=0)
```

```html
<input oninput="O.value=f(this.value)" value="Hello!"><br>
<input id=O value="HW^adY" disabled>
```

I can't believe there's no JS answer with this technique yet...

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and f(s[:-1])+chr(int(sum(map(ord,s))*1./len(s)+.5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRodiqWCExL0UhTaM42krXMFZTOzmjSCMzr0SjuDRXIzexQCO/KEWnWFNTy1BPPyc1T6NYU1vPVFPzf0ERUBFQm7pHak5OvqK6poKygkd4XGJK5H8A)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

```
putc gets.sum.quo(~/$/)+0.5
```

Solution produced through some collaborative golfing at work.

### How this works

- `Kernel#putc` prints a single character (e.g. `putc "Hello"` outputs `H`). Passing an object to it prints the character whose code is the least-significant byte of the object. So `putc 72` outputs `H`.
- `Kernel#gets` reads stdin and returns a string.
- `String#sum` returns a checksum. The result is the sum of the binary value of each byte in the string modulo `2**16 - 1`. Since ASCII bytes comfortably fit in this space, this just returns the byte total.
- Because the byte total is an integer, we can’t do floating point calculations (in Ruby `10 / 3`  is `3` whereas `10.to_f / 3` is `3.33…`). Here’s where `Numeric#quo` comes in – `10.quo(3)` returns the Rational  `(10/3)`.
- `Regexp#~` matches a regular expression against the contents of `$_` (the last string read by `gets`). It returns index of the match.
- The Regexp `/$/` matches the end of the string, so `~/$/` means “print the index of the end of the string” – in other words, the string length. This gives us the final  is a short-hand for the length of the string read by `gets`.
- This gives us the Rational (byte total/string length). Now we need to round it into an integer. `+0.5` casts the Rational to a float. `putc` floors the float into an integer.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>85</s> 81 bytes

```matlab
s->(i=[int(c)for c=s];print(join([char(iround(mean(i[1:j])))for j=1:length(i)])))
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts a string and creates a vector of its ASCII code points. Means are taken for each sequential group, rounded to integers, converted to characters, joined into a string, and printed to STDOUT.

Answer (score 2):

## K, 36 bytes

```
`0:_ci_.5+{(+/x)%#x}'.0+1_|(-1_)\_ic
```

Usage:

```
  `0:_ci_.5+{(+/x)%#x}'.0+1_|(-1_)\_ic"Hello!"
HW^adY
  `0:_ci_.5+{(+/x)%#x}'.0+1_|(-1_)\_ic"test"
tmop
  `0:_ci_.5+{(+/x)%#x}'.0+1_|(-1_)\_ic"42"
43
  `0:_ci_.5+{(+/x)%#x}'.0+1_|(-1_)\_ic"StackExchange"
Sdccd_ccccddd
```

`_ci` and `_ic` convert ascii to chars and vice versa, respectively. `{(+/x)%#x}` is a classic K idiom for calculating a mean. Pretty straightforward overall.

Edit: oh, misread the spec. `0: is needed to print the result to stdout. Waiting for clarification on input re. Dennis' question.

Comment: If you use K5, this can be shortened to 35 bytes: ``{[s]`0:`c${_.5+(+/u)%#u:x#s}'1+!#s}``.

Comment: Or 30: `\`0:\`c$_.5+{(+/x)%#x}'1_|(-1_)\ `

Comment: `\`c$_.5+{(+\x)%+\~^x}\`i$` for 24. It could be shorter (`\`c$\`i${(+\x)%+\~^x}\`i$`) but your REPL (http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html) isn't rounding correctly when casting from float to int. I'd hesitate to call this a k solution since `_ci` and `_ic` are nowhere in the K5 spec as far as I can tell, while `0:` doesn't print to stdout but instead reads a txt file from disk.

Comment: @tmartin: correct- `_ci` and `_ic` are entirely replaced in K5 with the forms like `\`c$`. The original solution I posted is compatible with Kona, which is based on K2/K3. I generally try not to post solutions with oK specifically because the semantics are still shifting around and partially inaccurate.

Comment: Ah i see, makes sense to me. I figured this was another K5 solution. Here's a 28 char kona solution `\`0:_ci_0.5+{(+\x)%1.+!#x}_ic`

Comment: @tmartin: Nice! I think I'll start specifying K dialects to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 71

```python
i=s=0
r=''
for c in input():s+=ord(c);i+=1.;r+=chr(int(s/i+.5))
print r
```

With each new character, updates the character sum `s` and the number of characters `i` to compute and append the average character.

Comment: Almost exactly the same approach as mine, only Python 2 instead of 3, and posted hours earlier: +1. (Also, I found I saved a few bytes printing each character as it came rather than storing them for one final `print`. Will that work with Python 2? I forget just now how to suppress newlines in the `print` statement... comma makes it a space instead, right?)

Comment: Python 2 can do `print _,` to leave a space rather than newline, but no good way to omit the space. Good call with Python 3's `end` argument, I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: @TimPederick Maybe the backspace control could be justified for a terminal that uses it, as a hack to delete the space: `print'\b'+_,`

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, <s>43</s> 31 bytes

*Thanks to [@beaker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42892/beaker) for 9 bytes off!*

Using an anonymous function:

```
@(s)[cumsum(+s)./find(s)+.5 '']
```

Examples:

```
>> @(s)[cumsum(+s)./find(s)+.5 '']
ans =
  function_handle with value:
    @(s)[cumsum(+s)./(find(s))+.5 '']
>> f=ans;
>> f('Hello!')
ans =
    'HW^adY'
>> f('test')
ans =
    'tmop'
>> f('42')
ans =
    '43'
>> f('StackExchange')
ans =
    'Sdccd_ccccddd'
```

Comment: Since all printable ASCII codes are non-zero, `find(s)` is 5 bytes shorter than `(1:numel(s))`. In Octave, `char` seems to do automatic rounding of non-integer values, saving another 7 bytes.

Comment: @beaker Thanks! How unexperienced I was back then. I didn't even remove `f=` from the count :-D Matab seems to round down rather than to nearest, so I had to include `+.5`

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 75 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode@Floor[.5+Accumulate@#/Range@Length@#]&@ToCharacterCode@#&
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathcad, 60 "bytes"

[image]

Mathcad is mathematical application based on 2D worksheets comprised of "regions" each of which can be text, a mathematical expression, program, plot or scripted component.

A mathematical or programming instruction is picked from a palette toolbar or entered using a keyboard shortcut. For golfing purposes, an operation ("byte") is taken to be the number of keyboard operations necessary to create a name or expression (for example, to set the variable a to 3, we would write a:=3. The definition operator := is a single keypress ":", as are a and 3 giving a total of 3 "bytes". The programming ***for*** operator requires typing ctl-shft-# (or a single click on the programming toolbar) so again is equivalent to 1 byte.

In Mathcad the user enters programming language commands using keyboard shortcuts (or picking them from the Programming Toolbar) rather than writing them in text. For example, typing ctl-] creates a while-loop operator that has two "placeholders" for entering the condition and a single line of the body, respectively. Typing = at the end of a Mathcad expressions causes Mathcad to evaluate the expression.

(Count bytes) By looking at it from a user input perspective and equating one Mathcad input operation (keyboard usually, mouse-click on toolbar if no kbd shortcut) to a character and interpreting this as a byte. csort = 5 bytes as it's typed char-by-char as are other variable/function names. The for operator is a special construct that occupies 11 characters (including 3 blank "placeholders" and 3 spaces) but is entered by ctl-shft-#, hence = 1 byte (similar to tokens in some languages). Typing ' (quote) creates balanced parentheses (usually) so counts as 1 byte. Indexing v = 3 bytes (type v[k).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
.pvyDSÇOsg/îç}J
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=LnB2eURTw4dPc2cvw67Dp31K&input=SGVsbG8h)

Comment: -2 bytes by removing `D` and `}`, and replacing `s` with `y`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen for how old this answer is there's a lot more than that :P. `.p` is a 1byter now too

Comment: Ah lol, forgot about `η` xD

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

```
£T±Xc)/°Y r d
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=o1SxWGMpL7BZIHIgZA==&input=IkhlbGxvISI=)

#### How it works

```
£   T± Xc)/° Y r d
mXY{T+=Xc)/++Y r d}
                     // Implicit: U = input string, T = 0
mXY{              }  // Replace each char X and index Y in the string by this function:
    T+=Xc            //   Add X.charCodeAt() to T.
         )/++Y       //   Take T / (Y + 1).
               r d   //   Round, and convert to a character.
                     // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: Ah, nuts; I thought the "non-competing" filter had been removed from the leaderboard, so I didn't see this before posting [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143175/58974).

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 11 bytes

```
c@V±X /°T r
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Y0BWsVggL7BUIHI=&input=IkhlbGxvISI=)

Answer (score 2):

**PHP**, **176 byte**

```
<?=(implode('',array_reduce(str_split($argv[1]),function($c,$k){array_push($c[1],chr(floor(((ord($k)+$c[0])/(count($c[1])+1))+0.5)));return[ord($k)+$c[0],$c[1]];},[0,[]])[1]));
```

Example:

```
>php cg.php Hello!
HW^adY
>php cg.php test  
tmop
>php cg.php 42
43
```

The biggest solution so far, but based on php it can't get much shorter I think. 2 bytes could be saved by removing the newlines.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I thought I might leave them in the post for better readability. But yeah, this is code golf. I'll remove them ;)

Comment: You can always include an additional version with padding for readability along side your short one.  I often do this when my code is too long to be entirely visible on most monitors.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zig](https://ziglang.org) 0.6.0, 84 bytes

```rust
fn a(b:[]u8)void{var t:u64=0;for(b)|c,i|{t+=c;b[i]=@intCast(u8,(t+(i+1)/2)/(i+1));}}
```

[Try it Online](https://godbolt.org/z/zoPvbW)

Formatted:

```rust
fn a(b: []u8) void {
    var t: u64 = 0;
    for (b) |c, i| {
        t += c;
        b[i] = @intCast(u8, (t + (i+1)/2) / (i+1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP 7, 79 bytes

As I don't have enough reputation to comment on cb0's answer to provide him hints to improve his answer (mainly using the char index method in a string and while to loop through a string).
But I still bothered to post it due to the large reduction in byte count.

```
<?php $i=$b=0;while($a=ord($argv[1][$i++]??'')){$b+=$a;echo chr(round($b/$i));}
```

I didn't find a way though to use the `<?=` shortcut and avoid undefined errors without using command line flags (this is why i used `$i=$b=0;`). This answer does not work in PHP 5 due to the `??` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 7 bytes

```
CKvṁ.+C
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiQ0t24bmBLitDIiwiIiwiSGVsbG8hIl0=)

`.+` should be `ṙ`, but there's a bug.

Comment: Has the bug been fixed?

Comment: No, lyxal closed it and claimed it wasn't a bug. https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/issues/1376

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 62 bytes

```
;;=sP=i 0W<=i+1i+1Ls;=aGs=t 0i;Wa;=t+tAa=aGa 1LaO+A/+t/i 2i"\"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKWzJloMkuKotyzJFssBRRyALyeUD@BIhyzC1suyTZFiOkL@e6@550cg2ucvdUinLmumXp1@mu8eJ@7dx/P0Vz@J0OUmGRTnh89d3o6a5kvKb2lJcPi6SFaKcZ7e1pZLPBM0kmfIsYWnK0nl2Sx9Nvfrh7OM75lWvlx8umF@9/v3ggu1Vr0dnb9kv1evFR@ZVxEenlwbt2cdTg/Tj2buDy79Zhc0s/Gizb95fbL17cAlqxWZ8F@Wsa1cMJhVg1SJGI7ZX7Z0dfsLNDDbJoq8Mvw@HKzSohmjQTKBJUxsJazRvzs9PiQg/9snIAdpmALk4FgTAb2C9j9JlYttX2dhuNskOiMrVOLxoHZ4fWd@DICzeh5y5n4Yh73nw77QIwui4CEvm8uBTFIRlrzyIYCli3ml03jvY6ZU7nPm8dd36boOQViDkdkFwEs1YiBqCZhNgLKK8SCybPTUbPCsZD5oNWCVIDutOl1kMK8Qcw3s5WzjFIrvyx@GT67jPIKPBQRzRw9PFhZ0dFM8X7OGOl0mxiOKk2YDvaWLBOrBbAobDWtfldXY9vc7Z0/PV2LIHr1o2QWnwKbM02pB1XnVsJkSo1S1Yvc5gudcTK4CzkaRFYi48CzjxXRL/zqbznGXL2U2SFxIPs3gx4be8VFJBO5rjOdoi8ewyz2U91pXIez2b9VnH7YAKRMptliflMs@YSiLBRnkUrGK4j3Ie3aSJQgEg0vlDklsx6FNA2NevTIGL6S0mR3zu2NI9fIPpPPQciFGol1fQ4bGU6Qsk2WS5sDCkTPq0z@BtHbAoEoWQJmBcdzoVplZHBA2YwQINioEQKCrwHZAtoqJk5V0CwqK8BGIZgK7yKAY0ttESBdY4ay@ChU/PpkA3KmcQfEzdks8zgI0Z644BWqw8UiwXC3S4rbJKrZjuN/MP3G44G2WoVF5kkMdQ4DBzJXLhlQ8dXQXEwhEuYLEbYJFDmCrJqD4KUy3EjVCjNJ3H1p7reDYaiMvaCDIwW6ZplD@ahlbxuTDC876jkZFCyb/MVrhJhYcqZFHYZOnB4Zu3X37bOv31/JthsSn3hm8U7K8L3qpJPj65fEFimeQkMsom7J/LSL2i2HtTxe66CuGB4452xskGZxDzXp25TvNMtTJfZhiiQFbpbjkvLFUs6QRAbpc8ZrR7s5xe@XtjiUNEuk31QQMoFnCuyqkFpGD/dppOWqrwUJdyUMiqADgVWoDof0J/jW7IvN26nWg8JuM@a5X5MmlBEup1zElYn0ZQQnCjhanVqpyAdqLtslGROz6/mc9T2Lmpe@BFWyuzfmRQ9@ctMmHerMFMEWP2p2KEpC3naWqZUB3mOtAi/gfI2RpkbMPvDt6fOdiMRaLB68mV57oupBOYAq/qreD/Sj6XDB@BkaOGtegBeHPww6fP3dBTPR1LHLZ1fNCnLx67QHB0cnrYZVOojkFDp7bUh3U4jhZOmmQ0Ahi@UnOU8Bmcu5ecscqIzQl7G3Yci9MwAc14SL4IoKtw3NR1I54tViJATuLjqoSgm/gY1RQPvIzvrC54Zm3sAh8x@Rdjo@ocdAYMtQiCEB2KgxuUYbtNRknxcnSspawdUBuuKGg@LXPsXTSiXo3tpyrNYIKi4i4UX4DiuuwcKp5lt90/pvhXUb4HSpAqfHSblClMl1abYtnGCGGPnPDMDvjUsiieOBHEdzlicSBPbVuEOXSDjVjhYdMcIPQdCn1idMRqIB0SKLzoJFk7K5RvKnsEvd55W@0gp@liTfMFaDAbIP/CxXyRZJah2GnlLZoVAFU4E60S8jH03b1faF1OF5YYSaYAfYJGwQwHKevggAfkMDzQG@oA1Sq9LFhkvZBmITyxQGlLd4Mc0kWuRgndkPnm0FK5sbLkN7Ak@QPmODzta3Zu1aJOl4gtrGRrhKdr6QFa0rpfDPJfOwM5KG5IZF35ZAdqndFcbGEPslUTGo327GqyXCuHivWSpkNru0DG@mFYZwZ3wuxj6oVKarcqUrWB7SWJMin2pRYme5YZAVlbpBfOKy/gwRA3H3SaiGfNdazdpptXv4@kYzHnXtO83VCwtl93C8BjwZvN1FHLDfjLslDR1zkhhj0BqKcBUZ2EeoklGVPLCI8Ypxv1aItrLFLD4M9ULvki5jgA02EQASAqXMZTHiorfXtzqsZRqR5y7PR6lZts9R1l2TCOOvQsZY2QdvXXstPIdpzV63gFU7eKzgYvrLbnDX7orvlBxHWTF2YbTOsSTWgKIQboQRZVyLBzDbc8JAr6fZInHUUtczXQwqNl7fTv/NAxO5sds/1Dpu3NTN/WmL5trDj/IK/XDBd3DFrzTW8EMjwiOiHrezoaRAsh8uA89j04i55J7P8k9RDKaI02DJGU9A7UiqtCQwHxR66MiW/TWNMNKU7N1YNDm2QK3CWoEGMrgu94tbhL8qRTsGwOszZPS56xh@gR/Msmc7i8lsltkgPPYp4lWckjvG3AiZ@zh4TdRfcJEEpBSF6yWZQtIc0eX@MqWneDHgdXkCeKZVrirwukXBdGRdI3aZTKFZeZfJpkRTzKe5nSfRmIJhvWqFy6yEcp9tBHsDqbpMmEfalgf9FSnvCbGOAMJZUxIxTW76t3m8gbkrRrQH/W9XJIybrSILE41upnWK@e@8wsEkPzuCDrQP6Q12aCYJ/VBkpadJhRNVGGKzhVa/ZFv0DarRC6kjEtjeAcYmrNJ/MBmyWzeIFplrHRl/3/15TRn2DKSJmytcGWUNoiTdl/2ftC6wbIuL3PagS@pvBVo93ahLN60eapymMK0PDaVcVDWzb1kH2TU5YSzf/1v@GXNcgQo/mDzsCkro3Dq7RhVXXr2z994VEzcHXjQbpG7dajSyHRoMRxWOM2yiRyIEWvp9kE5E9gnvh5zBxIa9Yxc8aRbCf16R5JDf59f7BruOVYXC1CYxLrmQ1o/S6VyQuKo8/Cbm3wvRSOXhEarLY8f1PL27X1vOBr7j1a/A@DEwLDJ4Yi1pcEPTaZM5QPFqLWnofDFA0SIv/FJj2IoidPAmifJNMIiiRYpiZRnsEmn9CPTVFcQpvqbMcdnE1xxWYv3HZRmO6BMDXKHxxmEc9wqGVRfhs7JLTbhe/3Nv6sRfdQ/H8hyyU09eve8/e/JmDw1r8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
OÆmƤ+.Ọ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//cFvusSXaeg939/z//98DKJivCAA)

```
OÆmƤ+.Ọ
O       - Get a list of character codes from the input string
   Ƥ    - Over prefixes:
 Æm     -  Get the mean
    +.  - To each, add 0.5
      Ọ - Convert from character codes to charcters. Decimals are rounded down.
```

Answer (score 2):

## brev, 146 bytes

```
(as-list reverse(c pair-fold-right(fn(cons(integer->char(inexact->exact(floor(+(/(apply + x)(length x))0.5))))y))'())reverse(c map char->integer))
```

124 with banker's rounding:

```
(as-list reverse(c pair-fold-right(fn(cons(integer->char(round(/(apply + x)(length x))))y))'())reverse(c map char->integer))
```

Which is still a lot. It's clear that a huge painpoint in brev is the type converting (chars to integers, strings to lists etc).

Answer (score 2):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 76 bytes

```
t(a,[c=1,s=0])=>String.fromCharCodes([...a.runes.map((i)=>(s+=i+.5)~/c++)]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZA9b8MgEIb3/AqKOoDs0PRrcsgSVeqeoaosN0JAbFQbLMBRpcj96@7ZsZsbOODe5@4FJXwchkhEmkv@mAa@KSjfHaI3tmQn75p9JfzeKR1IzhgTzHdWB9aIlhADShISbhL2Sn8fZJLQgmbD2RmFGmEsoeiyQhBn4ZGxbRcD4ijH77qu3R1OEY46xDG/PI3rIQr5/fYjK2FLjYvsn3VdvMEfX0J9TnDj2gl@nmAlpTpKCKXUAp@cJ9NwQDcZpO3sg9XalrGCKzA9u1ymRd20oL8KczO3GqOFX4kE319GSY/WOwRbMh5oj@lNJ0LQHgrXEuJ8eQF0m2X9qh/@AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

```
(0.5<.@++/%#)\&.(3&u:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NQz0TG30HLS19VWVNWPU9DSM1UqtNP9rcqUmZ@QrpCmoe6Tm5OQrqsP5JanFJQieiRGCHVySmJztWpGckZiXnqr@HwA)

### Explanation

```
(0.5<.@++/%#)\&.(3&u:)
              &.(    )  do this, the left verb then the inverse of this:
                 3&u:     characters -> ordinates
(           )\          over the prefixes of the input:
        +/%#            take the average (sum divide length)
 0.5   +                add one-half
    <.@                 then floor
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 62 bytes

```
c;t;main(n){for(;(c=getchar())>0;n++)putchar(((t+=c)+n/2)/n);}
```

[(ideone link)](http://ideone.com/HXZxxJ)

The results are slightly different from the OP's examples, but only because this code rounds 0.5 down instead of up. Not any more!

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>135</s> 127 Bytes

This got long real quick and I really got it wrong the first time:)  Need to read the questions properly.

```r
cat(sapply(substring(a<-scan(,''),1,1:nchar(a)),function(x)rawToChar(as.raw(round(mean(as.integer(charToRaw(x)))+.5)))),sep='')
```

Test Run

```r
cat(sapply(substring(a<-scan(,''),1,1:nchar(a)),function(x)rawToChar(as.raw(round(mean(as.integer(charToRaw(x)))+.5)))),sep='')
1: Hello!
2: 
Read 1 item
HW^adY
```

Comment: somebody posted a dupe challenge in the sandbox so I found this...This was a looong time ago, but `utf8ToInt` will help! I have a 68 byte golf of this if you want to update to it.

Comment: @Giuseppe Go ahead and post it yourself if you would like.  I suspect that it is significantly different to what I did here.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ruby 59 <s>61</s>

```rb
->w{s=c=0.0;w.chars.map{|l|s+=l.ord;(s/c+=1).round.chr}*''}
```

Test: http://ideone.com/dT7orT

Comment: `c+=1;(s/c)` → `(s/c+=1)` http://ideone.com/H2tB9W

Comment: @manatwork Well spotted! Thanks! I applied the change.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 100

Much like many other answers here, I'm summing and averaging in a loop. Just here to represent Java :)

```java
void f(char[]z){float s=0;for(int i=0;i<z.length;System.out.print((char)Math.round(s/++i)))s+=z[i];}
```

My original code is a 97, but it only returns the modified `char[]` rather than printing it:

```java
char[]g(char[]z){float s=0;for(int i=0;i<z.length;z[i]=(char)Math.round(s/++i))s+=z[i];return z;}
```

Now, it's *just* long enough for scrollbars to appear for me, so here's a version with some line breaks, just because:

```java
void f(char[]z){
    float s=0;
    for(int i=0;
            i<z.length;
            System.out.print((char)Math.round(s/++i)))
        s+=z[i];
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you show us a call sample too? My Java is very rusty.

Comment: As in how to call it? Assuming `test` is a char array, just use `f(test);`. If it's a String object, then you'd use `f(test.toCharArray());`. String literals are fine like that, too: `f("Hello!".toCharArray());`

Comment: Oh. Sure. `toCharArray()` Me stupid, I tried to violate it with some casting. Thank you.

Comment: It'd be way too easy to just cast it. The Java gods would be furious :P

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 41 bytes

```
say map{$s+=ord;chr($s/++$c+.5)}pop=~/./g
```

run as

```
$ perl -E 'say map{$s+=ord;chr($s/++$c+.5)}pop=~/./g' StackExchange
Sdccd_ccccddd
```

Answer (score 1):

### TSQL, 118 bytes

```
DECLARE @ varchar(400) = 'StackExchange'

SELECT
top(len(@))char(avg(ascii(stuff(@,1,number,''))+.5)over(order by number))FROM
master..spt_values
WHERE'P'=type
```

Returning characters vertical

```
S
d
c
c
d
_
c
c
c
c
d
d
d
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 30 bytes

```
i:0(?v
v &l~<
\+l2(?
\&,12,+o;
```

- The first line reads from stdin and puts the characters on the stack
- The second will remove the EOL char, take the size of the stack and put it in the `&` register
- The third line will add numbers on the stack while there are two or more of them
- The fourth line will divide the resulting number by the register's value, then add 1/2, output the value as a character and stop. When faced with a float value when displaying a char, ><> will floor it, which is why we added 1/2

You can try it on the [online interpreter](https://fishlanguage.com/) but then you need to use the following version, because the online interpreter pads the code box to a rectangle and applies `?` to spaces.

```
i:0(?v
v &l~<
\+l2(   ?
\&,12,+o;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
S÷L+.Ḟ
OµḣLR$Ç€Ọ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASMA3P//U8O3TCsu4bieCk/CteG4o0xSJMOH4oKs4buM////IjQyIg)

Only if there were Average and Round built-ins...

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 65 bytes

```
LINPUT S$FOR I=1TO LEN(S$)A=A-A/I+ASC(S$[I-1])/I?CHR$(A+.5);
NEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 69 bytes

```
#(for[c(map /(reductions +(map int %))(rest(range)))](char(+ c 0.5)))
```

Returns a sequence of characters, arguably a string-like construct. Would need an `#(apply str(for[...]...))` to convert it into a string.

Comment: 81 bytes with the string conversion.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
OÆmƤ+.ḞỌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//cFvusSXaeg93zHu4u@f///9KwSWJydmuFckZiXnpqUoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
zȯci/Nt∫mc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v@rE@uRMfb@SRx2rc5P///@vVFKal6gEAA)

```
                                                    | "tuna"
         mc  -- map each character to ASCII value   | [116,117,110,97]
       t∫    -- prefix sums & drop leading 0        | [116,233,343,440]
z(   )N      -- zip the list with [1..] using       | 
    /        --   divide                            | [116/1,233/2,343/3,440/4] == [116.0,116.5,114.̅3,110.0]
   i         --   round                             | [116,117,114,110]
  c          --   convert to character              | "turn"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
(0.5<.@++/%#)&.(a.&i.)\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0HDQM/URs9BW1tfVVlTTU8jUU8tU08z5n9qcka@QpqCem5ipUJJRqpCWn5RcqpCUqpCeWZJhkJlfqmOQmJOeWJlsToXWKk6lAZq8UjNyclXRPBLUotLEDwTIwQ7uCQxOdu1IjkjMS89Vf0/AA)

#### How it works

```
                      \  on prefixes
               (   i.)   index of the first occurence
               (  &  )   in
               (a.   )   the character set
            x&.y         apply y, then x, then the inverse of y,                            
(0.5        )              that is the element of a. with a given index
(       +/  )            sum
(          #)            number of elements
(         % )            division
(   <.@+    )            add, then floor
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 52 bytes

```sh
for c (${(s::)1})printf ${(#)$((.5+(n+=0.+#c)/++i))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLCsIwEEX3@YqRdjFDoD7QTcWl4N4vKNPEBMtMabIQpd8eo3d1OHDuO4XikbB4XYAB2w@mvqf9SvMSJXuooqEWsTtZFHvZdbZh2lobidZCxvy6BFHg5qZJN5BdynA8wD0P/Ly@OAzycGcY1UBd/Ut/cBzUjCrOlC8)

In arithmetic mode, `#c` gets the code of the first character of `$c`. The parameter expansion `${(#)    }` prints the character associated with the code.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 59 bytes

```powershell
-join($args|%{[char][int][Math]::Floor(($s+=+$_)/++$i+.5)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BasMwEETv@go1bGoJOS2k6cVgyCUll55yKMU4RkiK7cSxXGlLA46/3VVrQuY2b2Z2O/tjnK9M04xwSPtxcbR1y0C60l/nfaYq6fKsbjHP3iVWeZK8NdY6xsCLVEDBn4WAWjy98oGPAyFrRkjMom24Zx@iONp@7KX@jPgfROMxIDzbbgKrZbCrl8nsUKrT5hIetqUJfKeV0oUK0lqHCuH0Sue0JzQIPLq6LWMK5tIZhUbTlEIxZc747wYDeIQDXU/N/2QG7BYulPm6j3lyW83IMP4C)

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 25 bytes

```
{⎕UCS⌊.5+(+\C)÷⍳⍴C←⎕UCS⍵}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 45 bytes

```
s->t=i=0;Strchr([(t+=c)\/i++|c<-Vecsmall(s)])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN3WLde1KbDNtDayDS4qSM4o0ojVKtG2TNWP0M7W1a5JtdMNSk4tzE3NyNIo1YzWhmrwTCwpyKjWKFXTtFAqKMvNKgEwlEEdJIQ2oTlNHIVrJIzUnJ19RSUdBqSS1uAREmxiByOCSxORs14rkjMS89FQlmJELFkBoAA)

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 52 bytes

```
s->Strchr(Vec(intformal(Ser(Vecsmall(s))/(1-x)))\/1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN02Kde2CS4qSM4o0wlKTNTLzStLyi3ITczSCU8EixUB2jkaxpqa-hqFuhaamZoy-oSZUr3diQUFOpUaxgq6dQkERUCuQqQTiKCmkgbToKEQreaTm5OQrKukoKJWkFpeAaBMjEBlckpic7VqRnJGYl56qFAs1csECCA0A)

This one is longer, but I can't resist to do this:

- `Vecsmall(s)`: Converts the string to a vector of ASCII codes.
- `Ser(...)`: Converts the vector to a formal power series.
- `.../(1-x)`: Divides the result by \$1-x\$. This is equivalent to taking the cumsum.
- `intformal(...)`: Takes the integral with respect to \$x\$. This is equivalent to dividing the `n`-th term with `n`.
- `Vec(...)`: Converts the result back to a vector.
- `...\/1`: Rounds the result.
- `Strchr(...)` Converts the result back to a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 55 bytes

```c
n;t;main(c){for(;read(0,&c,1);putchar(t/++n))t+=c+n%2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P8@6xDo3MTNPI1mzOi2/SMO6KDUxRcNARy1Zx1DTuqC0JDkjsUijRF9bO09Ts0TbNlk7T9XIuvb//@CSxORs1wqgdF566r/ktJzE9OL/usUlKbbJFpYA)

#### How it works

```c
n;t;           // t and n are initialized to 0
read(0,&c,1)   // Reads a character from stdin into c,
               // returns the number of characters read, 0 if EOF.
t+=c+n%2       // t is the accumulator, n%2 is used to round up.
putchar(t/++n) // increment n and use the new value to calculate the average.
```

---

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 45 bytes

*Same idea, but as a function which modifies the string in-place.*

```c
n;t;f(*s){for(n=t=0;*s;*s++=t/++n)t+=*s+n%2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBNT8MwDD03v8IMbUu/oEzcuu6GxGHighCHbUKlSzeLzJ2ajCKm/XWKk4EQUhTZ7/nZz67SSpe06XvKbV7LyITHumklFbbI8sjwi@PCXscxhTYuOKPhJD/1l0iVPqwVTI1dY3O1nYl/kMZXhwkkK3YlknxvcB2KowiqbdlCpJEUFPDwNJ/nIugc@GIh6swfaPBTMUYu/I1bVa4TwFywZotagZQeY9VGWddUjtyfwIgScNYoDGEGWQg8OsAapKMXZ1EKNysoChgvaRwyHXguTT3LDBPZmMcH3haDWjeV7EwCBBE4T03tPIeuhq8GErkuywFhWpzN5hDH6Ht3ZoGup5@BKy@RP9p9y3eq5WBoIJ3BUJslDRI4L3IuOfHGdauUt@8An3hOBK2yh5Z4sDj194pNXgirjBW3E/Foy@rt7oPvSxv1VdW63Jg@faYmxd1eY4X2Gw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 21 bytes

```
)?^qavpa0.5?+)avqL[\m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V@trmBtrRv7X9M@rjCxrCDRQM/UXlszsazQJzom939teM5/j9ScnHxFhUdtkxQ8wuMSUyK5SlKLS8D8ktz8Ai4TIzDbxJgruCQxOdu1IjkjMS89FSwYnJKcnBKfDAQpKSkA)

```
)?^   # To codepoint
qavpa # Average on prefixes
0.5?+ # Add 0.5 to each
)av   # Floor each
qL[\m # Back to char
```

Should be 17 chars, but `R_` (round) rounds 0.5 down, not up.

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 59 bytes

```
N+X+[A|R]:-L=X+A,T is round(L/N),put(T),N+1+L+R.
+A:-1+0+A.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/3087QjvasSYo1krXxzZC21EnRCGzWKEovzQvRcNH309Tp6C0RCNEU8dP21DbRztIj0vb0UrXUNtA21Hvv5WugnaCR2pOTr5ignVejh4XWKAktbgEiWtihMQJLklMznatSM5IzEtPBYv/BwA)

Takes a list of codepoints and outputs to STDOUT.

A little longer, but using only one predicate:

### [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 63 bytes

```
+A:-scanl(plus,A,0,Z),nth0(N,Z,E),N>0,T is round(E/N),\+put(T).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcgxCsMgFADQvaewm@I3ldIphUIGoZNLM4UOEStJyEclKu3tLWTK@F7cAoZJpO9SK@9akazxSCOWBB1IGBj4PEuqYQDFQD8k9GRJZAvFf6i6aAZvHkumPWtqKwgfnw4xnMe7x@a0R3YpH3i7HvDKxq7qZ2fjJ7d//QM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `B`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƒ€m.+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpNS7IKlpSVpuhYrjk161LQmV097SXFScjFUcMEyj9ScnHxFCA8A)

##### Explanation

```python
ƒ€m.+  # Implicit input
       # Convert to ordinals
ƒ      # Prefixes of ordinals
 €m    # Mean of each
   .+  # Add 0.5 to each
       # Convert to string
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 106 bytes

Port of [@alephalpha's PARI/GP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251211/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU7NSsNAEL7nKcZQcJemsU1FJGEDIoKCnoon8TBu87Ntsim701IJeRIvBbHv1Ldx03QO88F88_38HK3ECueH03XztcokwRsqDa3n7bCCPGYLMkoXIh2Qg_jbUj65P62sSNsdGkaB4oJNw2kw44kNa9ww6SgaC5n0HihqpDI0zVYvGd0oHlLzosk97tk84mGtNJtFdzxRYzFL0LGPJZrOEeshs7sk_gIssxxq14-hKWwMD8bg98fw9cljeNeKQLjy4KbPtmfKuturssT856yqmis_AJ8ySz3eRv1eEMr1016WqIvM52f9RRvmjclQlsy5pLBxN6o0s_7IwiSFUZszyzuf95rOu1Q9HAb8Bw)

```scala
s=>{var(t,i)=(0.0,1);s.map(c=>{t+=c;val a=math.round(t/i).toInt.max(32).min(126);i+=1;a.toChar}).mkString}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVLBTgIxEE087t37uOHQRlkEjDFESJCYSCIn4skQU0qXrXa7pO0ChvAlXrjoR_k1TncLiZe2M_Nm5s3rfP1YzhTrHg7fpUubd79n58X8XXAHEyY17CKAhUghJbYHU2ekXtLjA_pVGGDNFKwFtzlTqgdDY9jn61i7GQJskrMVeUtcgQ6KVxUNWQYcQq6T65Mt0W6fLCMs2lpsQsOHUqqFMFEFSAsDhMN989SaBjqAZS_7wIPh2THLpa89YS5LTFHqBXHQAklrYkhyS7odmuRSk3bnlkKrBULb0gjYSJehECsk4NhcCRhOR-MxGKaXInTwPLFh1QQLjjJmQkR6fz3QvqaNWITU8xAaBb-XOEe9CTNLe5SwBs1Q7xct3T-1bRXy6jxL60j8JJQqLuIriJ2wzt83HX9OHeMfj1ueebYxrfJDboICCsYzglUG9XhKExs3LDQH0Njhj9N9TGuK-6jejrAkx2X5Aw)

```scala
object Main {
  def f(s: String): String = {
    val vecsmall: Array[Int] = s.map(_.toInt).toArray
    var t = 0.0
    var i = 1
    var res = new StringBuilder

    for (c <- vecsmall) {
      t += c
      val ascii = Math.round(t / i).toInt.max(32).min(126) // ensure within printable ASCII range
      res += ascii.toChar
      i += 1
    }

    res.toString()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val strings = List("Hello!", "test", "42", "StackExchange")
    strings.foreach(s => println(s"$s -> ${f(s)}"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES7, 122 bytes

```
s=>String.fromCharCode(...[for(i of s)i.charCodeAt()].map((l,i,a)=>Math.round(eval((t=a.slice(0,++i)).join`+`)/t.length)))
```

Mostly everything is happening in this bit

```
eval((t=a.slice(0,++i)).join`+`)/t.length)
```

The rest is looping / character code conversion

Split up:

```
s=> 
 String.fromCharCode(...                        ) // Converts average character code array to string, ... allows it to take an array
   [for(i of s)i.charCodeAt()]                    // Converts string to char code array
   .map((l,i,a)=>                             )   // Loops through each character
     Math.round(                    /t.length)    // Rounds sum of previous char codes, divides by position + 1
       eval(                       )              // evals string of char codes seperated with +
            (                ).join`+`            // joins previous char codes with +
             t=a.slice(0,++i)                     // creates an array with all the char codes
```

---

If functions aren't allowed:

```
alert(String.fromCharCode(...[for(i of prompt())i.charCodeAt()].map((l,i,a)=>Math.round(eval((t=a.slice(0,++i)).join`+`)/t.length))))
```

<sub>**133 bytes**</sub>

---

ES5 Snippet:

```js
function _toConsumableArray(r){if(Array.isArray(r)){for(var e=0,t=Array(r.length);e<r.length;e++)t[e]=r[e];return t}return Array.from(r)}function _taggedTemplateLiteral(r,e){return Object.freeze(Object.defineProperties(r,{raw:{value:Object.freeze(e)}}))}var _templateObject=_taggedTemplateLiteral(["+"],["+"]),f,t=function t(s){return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,_toConsumableArray(function(){var r=[],e=!0,t=!1,a=void 0;try{for(var n,i=s[Symbol.iterator]();!(e=(n=i.next()).done);e=!0){var o=n.value;r.push(o.charCodeAt())}}catch(l){t=!0,a=l}finally{try{!e&&i["return"]&&i["return"]()}finally{if(t)throw a}}return r}().map(function(l,i,a){return Math.round(eval((f=a.slice(0,++i)).join(_templateObject))/f.length)})))};

// Demo
document.getElementById('go').onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = t(document.getElementById('input').value)
};
```

```html
<div style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"><h2 style="font-family:sans-serif">Average of Words Snippet</h2><div><div  style="background-color:#EFEFEF;border-radius:4px;padding:10px;"><input placeholder="Text here..." style="resize:none;border:1px solid #DDD;" id="input"><button id='go'>Run!</button></div><br><div style="background-color:#EFEFEF;border-radius:4px;padding:10px;"><span style="font-family:sans-serif;">Output:</span><br><pre id="output" style="background-color:#DEDEDE;padding:1em;border-radius:2px;overflow-x:auto;"></pre></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 106 bytes

It's not short enough. Since it's python it's way too verbose, you can even read what it does by looking code. But it's working.

```py
a=[.0]+[ord(i)for i in raw_input()]
print"".join([chr(int(.5+(sum(a[:i+1])/i)))for i in range(1,len(a))])
```

Comment: "Since it's python it's way too verbose"... not compared to Java. And I disagree. Any less verbose and it wouldn't be as great as it is. Use Pyth if you want less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6, 111 bytes

```js
w=>w.replace(/./g,(_,i)=>String.fromCharCode([for(f of w.slice(0,++i))f.charCodeAt()].reduce((a,b)=>a+b)/i+.5))
```

This is annoyingly long thanks in part to JavaScript's long `String.fromCharCode` and `charCodeAt` functions. The stack snippet contains ungolfed, commented, testable code.

```js
f=function(w){
  return w.replace(/./g,function(e,i){
    return String.fromCharCode(w.slice(0,++i).split('').map(function(f){
      return f.charCodeAt()
    }).reduce(function(a,b){
      // Adds all numbers in the array
      return a+b
      // String.fromCharCode automatically floors numbers, so we add .5 to round up
    })/i+.5)
  })
}

run=function(){document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=f(document.getElementById('input').value)};document.getElementById('run').onclick=run;run()
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="Hello!" /><button id="run">Run</button><br />
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 80 bytes

```
[ cum-sum [ dup zero? 1 0 ? + / ] map-index [ .5 + floor >fixnum ] map >string ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 7 bytes

```
OÄ÷T+.Ọ
```

```
OÄ÷T+.Ọ  ~Main link
O        ~Cast to number
 Ä       ~Cumulative sum; add the values
  ÷T     ~Divide by indices
    +.   ~Add .5
      Ọ  ~Cast to characters
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6Fqv9D7cc3h6irfdwd8-S4qTkYqj4qmglD6C6fEWlWKgIAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 50 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and f(s[:-1])+[int(.5+sum(s)/len(s))]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3jdJscxJzk1ISFYqtihUS81IU0jSKo610DWM1taMz80o09Ey1i0tzNYo19XNS84CUZixMZ5JttFZuYoFGflGKjpJHak5OvqKSZixXpW2aRpImV0ERSDdERXJGkU6lZqwmRCfMbgA)

Takes in an list of UTF-8 codepoints, return a list of UTF-8 codepoints.

Answer (score 0):

## [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/), 210 bytes

*Saved so many bytes thanks to the comment of @ceilingcat*

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBNSwMxEP0rMXjIsB/WVbzEFEQUhRbEFjyUHsI2drNuE8hM18qy/vWadq14mXnzZpiZ90rMNt75/RatW7PZF5LZyP9FPjc7kmWjEdlLt0fSZEuGFA4jj@IXIHTWEasV5hPj1lSlVtWy1YG1yplPFpuLenkkSOWjIwiKc/nug5A2y8YjCe3CLtW9d60JlM/9s6OrQmAkYRhLEntbSwiJEqKsdICppiqfWicGoHdCxEMD/eq3biUEJeqwFi6ybwvpVQHpZXEDIIOhbXAsyP4kqfV2xaY6bhs0LZZ30J2gPqo4VR1/Mk3jz3jKySDFdF3EMCNdfjzs4mtubXh/eNrosvrzKLrANESB6BuTvwVLZmKdEee8w55lY9ZFP6HnIPt@/wM)

```
static string F(string s){int j=s.Length,i=j;var v=new int[j];var t=.0;var r="";for(;i-->0;)v[i]=Convert.ToInt32(s[i]);for(;++i<j;)r+=((char)Math.Min(Math.Max((int)Math.Round((t+=v[i])/-~i),32),126));return r;}
```

Ungolfed version. [Run it on dotnetfiddle!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IsNrWg)

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static string ConvertString(string s)
    {
        int[] vecsmall = new int[s.Length];
        for(int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
        {
            vecsmall[j] = Convert.ToInt32(s[j]);
        }
        
        double t = 0.0;
        int i = 1;
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

        foreach(int c in vecsmall)
        {
            t += c;
            int ascii = (int)Math.Round(t / i);
            ascii = Math.Max(ascii, 32); // ensure within printable ASCII range
            ascii = Math.Min(ascii, 126); // ensure within printable ASCII range
            
            res.Append((char)ascii);
            i += 1;
        }
        
        return res.ToString();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] strings = new string[] {"Hello!", "test", "42", "StackExchange"};

        foreach(string s in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{s} -> {ConvertString(s)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [209 bytes](https://tio.run/##TVBNSwMxEP0rMXjIsB/qVrzEFEQUhRbEFjwsPYTt2M26TSCZrpVlf3tNv8TLzJs3w8y8V4Vs7azbbYKxKzb7CYRr@b/I57glWbU6BPbW7wJpMhUL5Pcjz@IEAvTGEmtUyCdoV1SnRjWy0551yuI3i82yWRwIUvn1AXjFufx0XkgzjkxpFurR2Q495XP3amlUiBBJAJNlp7n7RoJPlBBVrT1MNdX51FhxBHorRLxzpN/dxi6FoETtF8NVkhhIRwWkN8UdgPRIG2@Zl8NZUefMkk113HaUVC4eoD9DfRBxrnr@gm3rLnjKCQPFdFvEMCNdfT1t42t2hXzYv4y6qv8siiYwDVFicC3mH94QToxFccn7MLBszPpoJwwc5DDsfgE "C# (Mono C# compiler) – Try It Online")