# String and ASCII

Tags: code-golf, string, binary

**The Challenge**

Given a non-empty string containing only lowercase or uppercase letters and no spaces:

- Sum up the [ASCII values](http://www.asciichart.com/) for each character instance in the input string.
- The sum will be converted to [binary](http://www.decimaltobinary.com/761-in-binary).
- And, the result will be the number of ones in the binary value.

**Input example:**

```
abcDeFAaB
```

1. Sum up the [ASCII values](http://www.asciichart.com/) for each character instance, so for this example: `97+98+99+68+101+70+65+97+66 = 761`.
2. Convert the sum (`761`) to [binary](http://www.decimaltobinary.com/761-in-binary). This will give `1011111001`.
3. The final result will be the number of ones (`7`).

So the output for this example is `7`.

**Winning Criterion**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: I'm wondering, what's with all the downvotes? Maybe this challenge isn't too hard but it's not trivial either. Currently it stands for a 0/-3 score. Why?

Comment: This is just three separate challenges that already exist mashed together: [sum of ordinals](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53675/45941) (the averaging part is a trivial addition), [decimal to binary](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69155/45941) (a subset of the linked challenge), and [count ones in binary](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47870/45941).

Comment: A mix of multiple existing challenge subsets, even if trivial, shouldn't be considered a duplicate, because in terms of code-golf the solution can be much shorter compared to the multiple ones combined. Indeed, there are already posted answers here of 5 bytes or less.

Comment: @seshoumara, it's true that sometimes doing A and B is shorter than doing A and then doing B, but only if A and B have something in common. Summing codepoints and bitcount are so orthogonal that only a language specialised for this challenge would do better than essentially taking separate answers to the previous questions and combining them.

Comment: Is there a maximum string length

Comment: Why didn't the MATL submission win?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
OSBS
```

**[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=T1NCUw&input=&args=ImFiY0RlRkFhQiI)**

How?

```
OSBS - Main link: s     e.g. "abcDeFAaB"
O    - ordinal (vectorises)  [97, 98, 99, 68, 101, 70, 65, 97, 66]
 S   - sum                   761
  B  - binary                [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
   S - sum                   7
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python3, <s>46</s> 40 bytes

```
lambda s:bin(sum(map(ord,s))).count("1")
```

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>65</s> <s>53</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

Counting the number of 1s in a binary representation is calculating the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of a number, a common procedure in cryptanalysis. There's an R package `boolfun`, described in [this journal article](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Lafitte~et~al.pdf), which handily has a function `weight` which computes the Hamming weight of any (base 10) integer. That makes our job a lot easier! The rest of the code just sums over the integer representation of STDIN, before sending that to `weight`.

```
boolfun::weight(sum(utf8ToInt(scan(,'')))
```

As an added bonus, this code works for UTF-8 as well as ASCII. There are 7 ones in the binary representation of the sum of 高尔夫 (that's *golf* in Mandarin).

A note for those playing along at home: unfortunately, `boolfun` is no longer hosted on CRAN, so if you don't already have it installed you'll have to do it manually with `install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/boolfun/boolfun_0.2.8.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`, rather than `install.packages(boolfun)`.

If you really don't want to use `boolfun`, you can achieve the same result with only two more bytes:

```
sum(intToBits(sum(utf8ToInt(scan(,''))))==1)
```

Comment: Nice idea with the boolfun package, +1!

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
sBs
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=c0Jz&input=J2FiY0RlRkFhQic)

Shortest language for this challenge, I think: `s`um, `B`inary, `s`um.

Comment: @Ajay Isn't this the winner by code-golf criteria?

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
ÇObSO
```

**Explanation**

```
 Ç      # convert to list of ascii values
  O     # sum
   b    # convert to binary
    SO  # sum as a list
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4dPYlNP&input=YWJjRGVGQWFC)

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + coreutils, <s>43</s> 49 bytes

**Edit:** corrected version based on [manatwork](/users/4198/manatwork)'s comments.

```sh
od -vAn -tuC|tr '\n ' +|dc -e?2op|grep -o 1|wc -l
```

**Explanation:**

The result is printed on STDOUT, with some warnings given on STDERR which can be ignored.

```sh
od -vAn -tuC       # get the ASCII value for each string character
|tr '\n ' +        # replace each whitespace with a plus (in dc, a warning will be 
                   #raised for each consecutive plus)
|dc -e?2op         # execute input, calculating the sum, then convert to binary
|grep -o 1|wc -l   # count how many ones exist
```

**Run:**

```sh
echo -n "abcDeFAaB" | ./script.sh 2> /dev/null
```

**Output:**

```sh
7
```

A similar solution is presented below (51 bytes), that had the potential to be shorter, but with *xxd* I can't concatenate multiple flags and also *dc* only understands upper case hex letters.

```sh
xxd -c1 -u -p|tr \\n +|dc -e16i?2op|grep -o 1|wc -l
```

Comment: I'm afraid this works only for the first 16 characters of the input string, because `od` wraps the output. :( Otherwise nice trick to just add the character address to the characters codes.

Comment: @manatwork Good catch, I can fix it with `od -An -tuC|tr '[\n ]' +`. However, I found a weird printing behavior if input is repetitive. With 32 'a's as input, *od* prints the first 16 values and then a '*' on the second line :( Do you know how to make it print absolutely each value? I think I have to use xxd instead.

Comment: Wow. Never noticed that weird behavior. But `-v` seems to get rid of it. BTW, no need for brackets in `tr`'s parameter.

Comment: @manatwork Updated my answer. Thanks for both suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7,<del>80</del>,76 bytes

*Thanks to kevin for saving **4 bytes***

```
int f(char[]a){int s=0,c=0;for(char i:a)s+=i;for(;s>0;s&=s-1,c++);return c;}
```

## Ungolfed

```
int f(char[]a){
    int s=0,c=0;
    for(char i:a)
        s+=i;
    for(;s>0;s&=s-1,c++);
        return c;
}
```

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it. I was just about to post this exact answer.. Btw, you can shorten it a bit to this: `int f(char[]a){int s=0,c=0;for(char i:a)s+=i;for(;s>0;s&=s-1,c++);return c;}` (**76 bytes**)

Comment: I need to learn more!...btw **Thanks**

Comment: Umm, I think you've incorrectly copied/golfed it from your IDE, since you now have the return inside the for-loop instead of behind it (you probably forgot the `;` after the for-loop). As you can see in my comment above it first does a for-loop `for(;s>0;s&=s-1,c++);` ending with semi-colon, and then it returns. And as for the learning part, I've been corrected a lot of times in the past as well. You'll learn it over time. I still have a lot to learn myself and my answers are still occasionally being golfed by others.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen oops!•••• and thanks..／人 ◕ ‿‿ ◕ 人＼

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>79</s> 76 bytes

```
foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$c)$s+=ord($c);echo substr_count(decbin($s),1);
```

[Test online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aae09eeaf196a2b6535735607873c498dda0c0d6)

Ungolfed testing code:

```
$argv[1] = 'abcDeFAaB';

foreach(str_split($argv[1]) as $c){
    $s += ord($c);
}
echo substr_count(decbin($s),1);
```

[Test online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8aa06c5a54488e9c0785fe9fce94021b6a65cc70)

Answer (score 1):

### R, 98 bytes

Was interested in how difficult this would be in R. Turns out you have to do a lot of conversions back and forth (in this solution at least) but I'm sure there should be a shortcut, especially if using packages (can't access any here at work).

```
sum(as.integer(rev(intToBits(sum(strtoi(sapply(strsplit(readline(),"")[[1]],charToRaw),16L)))))^2)
```

Could add an explanation if someone is interested.

Comment: Before I saw your answer I came up with a very similar solution, which you can see [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94582/59052). You have some unnecessary function calls which can be excluded (e.g. `rev`, which is needless as you just `sum` over everything anyway, and the call to `sapply` is not needed as `charToRaw` can handle strings with multiple characters). Nice that we ended up with the same solution though!

Comment: @rturnbull Nice, I knew there were some unnecessary stuff in there.

Comment: One more thing: the `L` after the `16` ensures that it is of type `integer` and not `numeric`, which is good practice for careful programming, but for code golf purposes you can (almost?) always omit it, saving a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 34 bytes

```
01\
(?\i:@+$0
?!\:2%:}-2,r+$:
n;\~
```

[Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=MDFcCig_XGk6QCskMAo_IVw6MiU6fS0yLHIrJDoKbjtcfg&input=YWJjRGVGQWFC)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 47 bytes

```
g 0=0;g n=mod n 2+g(div n 2)
g.sum.map fromEnum
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 36 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with input string ***without newline*** on STDIN:

```
echo -n abcDeFAaB | strsum.pl; echo
```

`strsum.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=unpack"%b*",pack N,unpack"%32W*"
```

If the sum of the ASCII values fits in a 16-bit integer you can leave out the `32` and gain 2 more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### Julia, 56 Bytes

```
f(s)=length(filter(i->i=='1',bin(sum(map(Int,[s...])))))
```

Convert to ascii value, sum up, filter for 1s, take length of result

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript ES6, <s>80</s> <s>78</s> 71 Bytes

```js
g=
    s=>[...s].map(c=>r+=c.charCodeAt(),r=0)|r.toString(2).split`1`.length-1
;

console.log(g.toString().length);    // 71
console.log(g('abcDeFAaB'))          // 7
```

Saved 7 Bytes thanks to @BassdropCumberwubwubwub

#### Breakdown

```
 [...s]                              // Split string into array of chars
 .map(c=>r+=c.charCodeAt(),r=0)      // Sum up ASCII values
 |
 r.toString(2)                       // Convert to binary (represented as string)  
 .split`1`.length-1                  // Count occurences of 1
```

Comment: You can change `[...r.toString(2)].map(c=>r+=+c,r=0)|r` to `r.toString(2).split\`1\`.length-1` to save 7 bytes

Comment: @BassdropCumberwubwubwub Thank you.

Comment: Can `match\`1\`g.length` work?

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, 53

```
(lambda(s)(logcount(reduce'+(map'list'char-code s))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 73 bytes

```
<?=substr_count(decbin(array_sum(array_map(ord,str_split($_GET[s])))),1);
```

save to file, call in browser with `<scriptpath>?s=<string>`

or

```
<?=substr_count(decbin(array_sum(array_map(ord,str_split($argv[1])))),1);
```

save to file, run with `php <scriptpath> <string>`

---

To run without a file, replace `<?=` with `echo<space>` in the second version
and run with `php -r '<code>' <string>`.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>72</s> 70 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to ETHproductions:

```js
f=
  (s,p=([c,...d])=>c?c.charCodeAt()+p(d):0,q=n=>n&&n%2+q(n>>1))=>q(p(s))
;
console.log(f('abcDeFAaB'));
```

**Explanation:**

```js
(s,                                        //Input string
    p=([c,...d])=>c?c.charCodeAt()+p(d):0, //Recursive method to sum up the ASCII values
    q=n=>n&&n%2+q(n>>1)                    //Recursive method to count 1s in the binary form
)=>q(p(s))
```

---

**Previous solution (72 bytes):**

```js
(s,p=([c,...d])=>c?c.charCodeAt()+p(d):0,q=n=>n&&(n&1)+q(n>>1))=>q(p(s))
```

Comment: Nice. You can golf `q` like so: `q=n=>n&&n%2+q(n>>1)`

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <strike>51</strike> 50 bytes

```
s=>Convert.ToString(s.Sum(x=>x),2).Count(x=>x>48);
```

can be used like this:

```
Func<string, int> f=s=>Convert.ToString(s.Sum(x=>x),2).Count(x=>x>48);
f("abcDeFAaB") // == 7
```

would be so much shorter if Int32.ToString() had a to binary flag.

Edit: saved one byte by converting '0' to int

Comment: As far as I remember, `x=>x` inside `Sum()` is not required, although I'm not sure if it'll do the implicit cast to integers...

Comment: I tried that but there is no .Sum() for string

Comment: That's what I feared. How about changing the `'0'` literal to 48? You actually have it in your example, but not at the golfed code.

Comment: of course, stupid me forgetting halve the code

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
ssM.BsCM
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ssM.BsCM&input=%22abcDeFAaB%22&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
      CM  (M)ap ordinals(C) over input
     s    (s)um
   .B     Binary string
 sM       map cast to integer
s         sum
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, <s>53</s> 37 bytes

not the best solution but hey...built-in's ftw

Shortened. Thanks to Martin Ender

```
DigitCount[Tr@ToCharacterCode@#,2,1]&
```

Comment: `ToCharacterCode` can be called directly on a string. `Total` can be shortened to `Tr`.