# Average of your code

Tags: code-golf, string, self-referential

[Inspired by this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53675/calculate-average-characters-of-string)

## Task

Your task is to output the average character of your code.

### What is an average character?

Say we have a string `golf()`.
We then take the ASCII value of each separate symbol, so our string is `103 111 108 102 40 41`, and calculate the average of those values, rounded to an integer. In our case the average is `505 / 6 = 84.1666... = rounded to 84`. That value is printed out as an ASCII character, in our case `T`.

## Rules

You must take no input and must not read the source code directly, while outputting the average character of its source code. Integers are rounded by function `floor(x+0.5)`. Empty programs are not allowed. This is code-golf, so lowest byte count wins!

Comment: [Average Character Calculator](https://tio.run/##HYtBCoAwDATvviLHFKEK4tHHSI20UJOSxoOvr9W5LAM75bEovLRWYYPE5TZ0g4ntuXu9LxQ9MDg4RSH0A1Q3FE1sGKLit7NfYYQ/mTIxVtdpjdioJ3IQRFLyLw) (only works for unicode characters input)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman will update rules

Comment: While I like the idea, it would have been beneficial to restrict code to contain at least two different characters, neither of which can be identical to the average.

Comment: @Adám yeah, for some reason I didn't think of hardcoding the output... Maybe somebody could turn this into an interesting question, as I think its too late to edit this question.

Comment: @Dion You could post in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) a variant where the scoring works best for longer programs, or where the average/sum plays some role (just spitballing ideas)

Comment: @Dion Are empty program allowed, and if allowed should they output a null char or nothing.

Comment: @Mukundan314 empty programs are allowed as long as they output the average character, which is the NULL byte for an empty program

Comment: @Dion Empty program would result the average value of `round(0 / 0)`. It is invalid simply due to divided by zero. So I don't think the empty source code should be allowed. If it must be allowed, by using the definition of division, `x / y = z` is `y * z = x`, one may argue output any single character should be allowed.

Comment: @tsh ok, thats reasonable. Will edit the rules.

Comment: @Dion is returning the value from a function allowed

Comment: @Mukundan314 yes, as returning is printing to the functions output.

Comment: Downvoted - the challenge mostly boils down to "output one given character". There *might* be very special situations where the self-reference makes this harder - but if you have a primitive like print("?") where ? can be replaced by any other character, then it's easy to convert it into a solution (in particular, repeatedly replacing '?' by the average will always converge).

Comment: Does a `cat` script count as "reading the source code directly"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 1 byte

```
A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/3/H/fwA)

As it is 1 byte, simply outputting the source code gives the average. `///` just outputs the source code unchanged if it doesn’t contain any `/` characters, so almost any ASCII character works in place of `A`

Comment: +1 Right tool for the job.

Comment: Could we do a CW of languages which can implicitly output a single character? [Retina](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3@D/fwA), [Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/g/38A), etc.

Comment: @fireflame241 Looks like Adàm may have Beat you to it

Comment: Also works for Charcoal.

Comment: Also works for Keg/Canvas/Carrot.

Comment: Also works for cat

Comment: Cat is a programming language?

Answer (score 23):

## [Unreadable](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unreadable), 111 bytes

> '"'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K80rSk1MSUzKSf3/X11JXYl@SOn/fwA) or [Check average](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P@/upK6Ev2QEgA)

Note that the average character is `$` and does not appear in the source code, which contains only 37 `'`s and 74 `"`s.

Answer (score 18):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 17 bytes

```
(=<;:9876543210TA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/1/D1sbaytLC3MzUxNjI0CDE8f9/AA)

[Test the code average](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P@/hq2NtZWlhbmZqYmxkaFBiCMA)

Explanation:

```
(=<;:9876543210TA

(                    Copies the value pointed by register d to register d.
                     (d = 0 so it copies the '(' ASCII value)
 =<;:9876543210      Succesive calls to the crazy operation to update the value
                     in register a until the value stored meets the code average
               T     Prints the value in a
                A    Ends the program
```

Luckily this time we don't need to cope with Malbolge's code encryption feature.

Answer (score 15):

## [HQ9+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9+) Family, 1 bytes

```
Q
```

Believe it or not, there are challenges can be solved by HQ9+ in 2020.

Comment: Don’t know whether this counts as indirectly or “directly reading own source code.” But I upvoted immediately for the clever meta-ness and original use of such a ‘done’ language!

Comment: This challenge can also be solved by cat in 2020.

Comment: The fact that you can solve this challenge with HQ9+ and also with cat makes it a particularly lame challenge in 2020.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 8 bytes

```python
print"Y"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EKVLp/38A)

[Average Character Verified](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P8/WJFSpBIA)

Comment: Also compatible with Lua

Comment: And with Perl too!

Answer (score 13):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/) and lots of other languages and REPLs, 1 byte

```apl
4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L8JiPqvAAYFAA)

---

However, more interesting is:

```apl
''''
```

Which actually evaluates to the single quote. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L86EIBY/xXAoAAA)

Answer (score 12):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 15 bytes

```
+[+++++>+<]>++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1obBOy0bWLttLX1/v8HAA)

Requires an 8 bit interpreter as it uses modulo 256 arithmetic.

Average is 53.4. Outputs `5` which is character 53.

Answer (score 8):

## [COW](https://bigzaphod.github.io/COW/), <sup><s>11</s></sup> 8 bytes

```
BOOM!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S84v///fyd/fV1GRi@v/fwA) or
[verify the average](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBVkHJyd/fV1ExJi8mT4mrJL8kMQcoWFyaq5FflKKRrKmQll@kkKyQmadQrMlVUJSZV6KRnFGkAaIN9EwVtBXAWvRzUvM0ijWB4P9/AA).

Explosively prints `0` (average 48.375), using the fact that all non-instructions (`B`, `!!`, and the two newlines) are no-ops.

#### 6 bytes

I'm retaining the 8-byte version above because it's my favourite, but here's a 6-byter thanks to @JoKing:

```
OOM!
```

(Note the code ends with two tabs.) Also prints `0` (average 47.66...).

And here's another, with an average of exactly 48:

```
OOM!
```

---

## [COW](https://bigzaphod.github.io/COW/), <sup><s>87</s></sup> 78 bytes

```
MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOMMMMOOmoOMoOmOoMOomooMMMMOomoomoOMoo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S84v///fN9@fKOTv7wsE/v65YG6uf76vf35ufj5YEMQAi@f//w8A) or [verify the average](https://tio.run/##jUtLCsMgFNznFG/5JNAWQpY5grwzFNugEB3Rl0VPb4wn6DAwH2byTz3S0lqljULKp7KZFPo@eq5nZJQPO0M7Crk@oGqmXEJSdr7wra/HSjONy/P4Jq6mozUL@YsitkMkjhgFVhCBUd5m9LgA).

No no-ops this time. Prints `[` (average 90.54...) by counting up to 91.

#### Commented

```
MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoO    push 13 to first memory block
MOO        begin outer loop
  MMM      copy value to register
  MOO      begin inner loop
    moO    switch to second memory block
    MoO    increment                                  
    mOo    switch to first memory block
    MOo    decrement
  moo      end inner loop
  MMM      paste register value into first memory block
  MOo      decrement
moo        end outer loop
moO        switch to second memory block
Moo        print as ASCII character
```

Comment: BOOM!! Out of mana! - Don't we know those lines?

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 8 bytes

```r
cat("B")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREPJSUnz/38A) or [Check average](https://tio.run/##HYtBCoAgEEX3nmJwNUNQQbRs001kKhRMRcdFpzfrbx4P3k@P2BiW1gps4EKqgqQkivHdS70x5gOZ4IoZuAdQSKXsgiDbjB/ncYUB/svkz4CF@lpjI6h3TS8)

or

```r
cat('C')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREPdWV3z/38A) or [Check average](https://tio.run/##HYtBCoAgEEX3nmJ2zhBUEC1bdRKZCgVT0XHR6c36m8eD99MjNoaltQIbuJCqICmJYnz3Um@M@UAmuGIG7gEUUim7IMg248d5XGGA/zL5M2ChvtbYCOpd0ws)

Also,

```r
cat(8)
```

(with 2 null bytes) doesn't work on TIO, but works in RStudio on my Kubuntu machine.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRIPRglHz/38A) or [Check average](https://tio.run/##HYtBCoAgEEVx6ylmOUNQQQRtOoxMhYKp6Ljo9Gb9zePB@@kRG8PSWoEdXEhVkLREMb57qTfGfCATXDED9wAK6ZRdEGSb8eM8rjDAf5n8GbBQX2tsBDdS6gU).

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 29 bytes

```
   ^
  / \
 /out\
^-----
-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsSszNTNEtTs5IzU39/19BQSGOS0FBXyGGS0E/v7QkhitOFwS4dLm4FP7/BwA)

This has an average of ~48.137, so this outputs `0`.

If we're allowed a trailing newline, then we can get 4 bytes

```
^,
-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsSszNTNEtTs5IzU39/z9Oh0v3/38A)

Again, this outputs `0`, but by printing the return of the pyramid, which has an extra newline

Answer (score 5):

## [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29), 1 byte

```
a
```

If your challenge can be competitively solved with `cat`, there is probably something wrong with the challenge.

Comment: Assuming `cat` is allowed, isn't this reading its own source code?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz No, `cat` is just the interpreter. Every interpreter has to read the source code of the program. There's no instruction in this program which reads the source code, only one that outputs the letter `a`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 1 byte

```
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/f4P9/AA) Works by counting the number of `0`s in the input. This can of course be extended to any arbitrary number of bytes just by repeating the number of `0`s, or substituting other characters which happen to have an average byte value of `0`, e.g. `.2`, as long as the result remains a valid regular expression that doesn't match the empty string.

Without using a Match (count) stage, I think the minimum possible is 3 bytes:

```
^
4
```

This program outputs `4`, whose ASCII code `52` is the average of `94` (for `^`) and `10` (for the newline).

Comment: If `0` outputs `0`, what stops a `.2` outputing `0` too?

Comment: @tsh Yeah, I thought of that myself overnight, almost any two ASCII characters with an average of `0` will work.

Answer (score 4):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), <s>19</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
v<<<<
>%(9@
```

-6 bytes thanks to *@JoKing*.

The average is 57.090..., which will be rounded to 57 (character `'9'`).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8wGCLjsVDUsHf7/BwA) or [verify that it's deterministic](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8wGCLjsVDUsHf7//68bBgA).

#### Explanation:

**Explanation of the language in general:**

Lost is a 2D path-walking language. Most 2D path-walking languages start at the top-left position and travel towards the right by default. Lost is unique however, in that ***both the start position AND starting direction it travels in is completely random***. So making the program deterministic, meaning it will have the same output regardless of where it starts or travels, can be quite tricky.

A Lost program of 2 rows and 5 characters per row can have 40 possible program flows. It can start on any one of the 10 characters in the program, and it can start traveling up/north, down/south, left/west, or right/east.

In Lost you therefore want to lead everything to a starting position, so it'll follow the designed path you want it to. In addition, you'll usually have to clean the stack when it starts somewhere in the middle.

**Explanation of the program:**

All arrows will lead the path towards the leading `>` on the second line. From there the program flow is as follows:

- `>`: travel in an east/right direction
- `%`: Put the safety 'off'. In a Lost program, an `@` will terminate the program, but only when the safety is 'off'. When the program starts, the safety is always 'on' by default, otherwise a program flow starting at the exit character `@` would immediately terminate without doing anything. The `%` will turn this safety 'off', so when we now encounter an `@` the program will terminate (if the safety is still 'on', the `@` will be a no-op instead).
- `(`: Pop the top value, and push it to the scope. This is basically used to make the stack empty if we started somewhere in the middle.
- `9`: Push a `9`
- `@`: Terminate the program if the safety is 'off' (which it is at this point). After which all the values on the stack will be output implicitly. So it'll output the `9` for the average character of unicode `57`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0`, 67 bytes

I know this isn't the shortest, but I think it's what OP was after.

```perl
$_=q{$_="\$_=q{$_};eval";$-+=ord for/./g;say chr(.5+$-/y///c)};eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rawGkgoxUBZtdapZYk5StYqutq2@UUpCmn5Rfp6@unWxYmVCskZRRp6ptoquvqV@vr6yZoQtf///8svKMnMzyv@r@trqmdooGcAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATLAB](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/index.html)... and MS-DOS and Bash? 7 bytes

```
!echo P
```

Outputs `P`. [Length verification](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P@/YmpyRr5CAAA)

---

*First post here.*

I thought this was going to be easy with MATLAB, as you can just enter a single digit number and it will return that as-is. Except that MATLAB prints more than just the number back out...

```
>> 0
ans =
     0
```

Same goes for strings.

```
>> 'a'
ans =
    'a'
```

Now I might've just waved my hands and said good enough, but where's the fun in that? :)

The only methods I knew of, that can print something to console without the extra `ans =`  would be to use the `fprintf()` or `disp()` functions.

**12 Bytes**.

```
>> fprintf('T')
T
```

**9 Bytes**. *Note, `Disp(0)` and other single-digit variations will not work due to average length constraint.*

```
>> disp('J')
J
```

These two are valid submissions, but I kept wondering... *Can I do better?*

Then I learned I could send commands to the operating system with the [Shell Escape Function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html). i.e. `!COMMAND`

*Except the command is sent to whatever operating system that machine is running on.* Since MATLAB is available for both Windows and Unix, whatever command I choose needs to work on both; ensuring that my code runs on all machines.

This more or less locked me to the single command; `echo`. *(Kinda anti-climactic, really)*

A few trials and error with the output character, and I converged to the final answer. **7 Bytes**.

```
>> !echo P
P
```

---

*I really hope this isn't breaking any rules here...*

Answer (score 3):

## [MAWP 0.1](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 3 bytes

```
99:
```

Outputs 9. Works because `:` and `9` are neighbours in the table, so `9:` gives a value thats in between them, so adding another `9` guarantees that the average corresponds to `9`

Answer (score 3):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 6 bytes

```
"o@7"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/18p38FcSeH/fwA)

### Explanation

```
"  7   Start a quote, then the character 7
 o  "  (backwards) End a quote, output the character
  @    Stop the program + no-op.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 3 bytes

```
0!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/99A0eH/fwA) or [Check the average character](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P@/gaIDAA)

### Explanation

```
0     Set current memory edge to 0
 !    Output current memory edge as a number
  @   Terminate the program
```

Answer (score 3):

## [SuperMarioLang](https://github.com/charliealejo/SuperMarioLang), 2 bytes

```
:%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky4tSC3KTSzKzM9JzEv//99K9f9/AA)

A simple answer in SuperMarioLang. The only command that gets executed is `:` which prints the value of the currently pointed memory position (0) as a number (initially 0). The second command `%` never gets executed as Mario (the command pointer) falls because there is no floor under him, so the program stops. The average between `:` and `%` is `0`.

Also [works in MarioLANG](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL///fSvX/fwA), where `%` is just interpreted as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 4 bytes

```java
A->9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xC4MwEIV3f8WNsWD2Ii10ceskuJQO12jkbEwkuQil@NvTVByOx/se996EK1ZT/040L84zTNnLyGSkjlYxOStPdaEMhgB3JAvfAoAsD16jGqDZ/U5Ai85RD2tZZ7TlW@LLkILAyFnWfzjnCtGyJzs@noB@DOXR0ICGC6RbdT2neiftJ/AwSxdZLvmBjRVaamGjMeWxsaUf)

Outputs the number `9` which as a character is the average character of the code.

Defined as a `int f(Void v)`. Note that `Void` is an accepted argument type for "no input" challenges.

If an `int` isn't an acceptable output for this challenge, the following is most definitely valid, for an extra byte.

```java
A->56
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU2xCsIwFNz9ijemQrPpUhRcujkVXMThmTb11TQpyUtBpN8eY@lwHHfH3Q04Yzm070Tj5DzDkLWMTEbqaBWTs3Jf7ZTBEOCKZOG7AyDLndeoOqhXDaBe6EGLm6MW5qLK3pIxxachBYGRM83/cMwbomFPtr8/AH0fim2iBg0nSJfyfDimarWaT@BulC6ynHKDjRVaamGjMcV2sqQf)

Outputs `8` which is the average character.

Defined as a `char f(Void v)`. I was surprised that no casting to `char` was required, but it beats `v->';'` by one byte.

Comment: It's an implicit narrowing conversion; any constant integer expression whose value is between 0 and 65535 can be used where a `char` is expected.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 10 bytes

```python
print("N")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8lPSfP/fwA)

Comment: either `print("O")`
or `print('P')` works too

Comment: A more fun idea is ````print(chr(82))````.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 6 bytes

```
$><<?8
```

average is 56.16

```
$ cat mean.rb
$><<?8
$ ruby mean.rb
8
$ python -c "[print(chr(int(0.5 + sum([ord(c) for c in s])/len(s)))) for s in [l.strip() for l in open('mean.rb')]]"
8
```

Comment: `p ?E` outputs `"E"`, but I don't think it's acceptable.

Comment: oops, somehow I dropped the leading char when calculating the average.  Fixed.

Comment: Your code works fine now. The average is still wrong, though.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (Browser), 10 bytes

```javascript
alert('M')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY6xDoMgFEV3v@KlC7xo0bGJsUnj3KlrBwlStKFggPr7FEgHx/ty7n3nzXfuhVu3cN4vUdhZwgBT5Fq6QMmdYJyYk5vmQtL2aVrVACHYV1UhEius8VZLpq2qqkOg5ESghrJYQwq5JHeuaT7lcIQfwa1GsZezn3HhbkxI4Zjf9JpECCaL@ZskqG9AIAxX8HmeiT9@C7RDaMtDpqVRYWmgQ8Q@/gA)

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY1BCoMwFET3OcXHTfLVRpcFsVA8Qi9giL9qSY0kqddPNbTgbt7wmHmpTXnt5jVctmvUdiBoIVOGXOinPqvy@M8xrxhLsBvaLt4aksaOjJ1A8IxDAWmngB2wYYw2ZcRRHXCWH8HNyyifzr67SbluV5In/WrmIDhH6Wj4aBLCl6AR2hv4Y17qn34Pokao0qE0tIxhKqFGxCZ@AQ).

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge-93, <strike>5</strike> 3 bytes

```
.@!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X89B8f9/AA)

`.@` prints `0`. `!` was added so the average is `47.667`, which rounds to `48`, which is the ASCII code for `0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), 9 bytes

```
SELECT"@"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7MySxJ/f8/2NXH1TlEyUHp/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 16 bytes

Outputs `6`, the average of the program.

```
-[>+<-----]>+++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO20YXBGLttLW19f7/BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 5 bytes

```javascript
()=>3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@19D09bO@H9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqbmfwA)

Comment: That returns 3, but outputs nothing.

Comment: @GirkovArpa, [Functions are allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/91267) and [function may output by return value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2456/91267)

Comment: The example specifically says `printed out`.

Comment: @GirkovArpa the rules explicitly say "outputting".

Comment: If I type `3` in my browser console and hit `Enter`, it outputs `3`. Would that win?

Comment: @GirkovArpa that would but that only works on a repl environment

Comment: I just realized you can save a byte with `_=>3`.

Comment: @GirkovArpa the average of `_=>3` would be `C` not `3`

Comment: My mistake I had totally forgotten the goal of this challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## [AlphaBeta](https://github.com/TryItOnline/alphabeta), 10 bytes

```
edaaaaaCLz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8wpyEhMSi1J/P8/NSURBJx9qv7/BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0
```

Or any other single digit.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4P9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 4 bytes

```
00000000: 3e 91 ff 76
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSMUxUsDRXS0hTMzRQUFP7/BwA)

This is `ld a, 0x91` → `rst 0x38` (putchar) → `halt`.

It prints a single `0x91` byte, and `(0x3e + 0x91 + 0xff + 0x76) / 4 = 0x91`.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 7 bytes

```
@echo U
```

I used the average character calculator to calculate the average of `@echo`  (with trailing space) and just appended the result, as that won't change the average.

Answer (score 2):

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), 59 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
TALK TO THE HAND "A"
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzKy89JSf7/3zNEPVgh2MM/PMTT15UrxNHHWyHEXyHEw1XBw9HPRUHJUYkr0j8UyAlzVXBydfVTCHEN8vX0cwxxdfn/HwA)

[Test the average](https://tio.run/##hY3BCoJAGITvPcVgh1aEkqJjhw0XlFIht6KjbBsKtivrivT0tlb35jL/MD/ftC9babUZxw471KrtLfFnVtuycbnrn0SbOxE@HtpAuAd0PgKsQ/w0R@DC1NpKwg4aSg5NrSREVZpSWGm6WWtqZYmoDJk8XG4d4rOxIo1U5Iv0nSaeA/7hjWPCFwWKOL/yJGWcHg/gOXjMENMsgke9W35294Vhz1gGzk5pklHOojc)

Mandatory answer in ArnoldC. New line characters have been added to the average as a single character of value 10.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by 'New line characters have been added to the average *as a single character*'. But with `"B"` and two newlines the average I get is 65.4237288, which rounds down to 65 (A).

Comment: @Dingus you're totally right, I don't know Python and I messed up the code of the average calculator trying to adapt it. ^__^U

Comment: I had similar problems myself with newlines not being counted properly by that Python code. [Here](https://tio.run/##HYyxCsIwFEX3fsUliymCCuLoEOmDFm0L9qkIWaQqLdSkJHHw62P1LocznDt@QmfNOkaPLUTBswZNXl@4KEkbVoc9uAbnhFxVGbRQWmhzrU@Tnwk7ogpMx7KoFFMmkmDDbZie/PslrbvLNsXTOrToDXyajK43Qbadkz@uFhvM8U@Ww8NIn06L8Qs) is another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 1 byte

```powershell
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/3@D/fwA)

This will work with every single digit. It just gets echoed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vim](https://vim.org), 2 bytes

```
ii
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/PzPz/38A)

Comment: This is a V submission. a Vim submission would require an `esc` at the end.

Comment: @Razetime Why would an `esc` be required? Even though Vim is still in Insert mode, the intended text has still been outputted. `esc` would just be moving it out of insert mode and into normal mode, but as far as I can tell, there is no requirement for a Vim submission to end in normal mode, or that it can't end in insert mode.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's the same reason why `2i2i` is a V quine rather than a vim quine

Comment: I think a [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22099/does-a-vim-submission-have-to-end-in-a-certain-mode/22101#22101) on this would be good.

Comment: 2i2I does not double the input until <esc> is pressed, that's why it's required there. This answer should be fine

Answer (score 2):

## [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), 4 bytes

```
����
```

Is this the first time where a lenguage program is totally written?

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 14 bytes

```
+[+++++>+<]>.�
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1obBOy0bWLt9Bj@/wcA)

Forcefix average

Comment: [13 bytes BF](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1pbW9tO2ybWTu/w@sPr//8HAA) with [proof of average](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P@/drS2tradtk2snd7h9YfXAwA)

Comment: @Bubbler https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII says ASCII is 0-127

Comment: Please provide a hexdump for programs containing unprintables. I can tell that your Lenguage program is made entirely out of null bytes, but please specify next time, as they show up as �.

Comment: @Makonede Do `&#0;` in every browser show `�`?

Comment: Pretty sure yeah. I don't think it's browser-dependent though, as searching it shows that it is shown as the real U+FFFD.

Answer (score 2):

## vim, 3 bytes

Four versions; one for each of the "insert on the same line" commands: `A`, `a`, `i`, and `I`:

- `A.<ESC>`
- `a><ESC>`
- `iB<ESC>`
- `I2<ESC>`

`<ESC>` is 0x1b.

(We can shave off a byte if we're willing to terminate while still in insert mode.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/31FP@v9/AA) (For the `A.<ESC>` variant)

Answer (score 2):

## [Sandwich](https://tildegit.org/sandwich), 2 bytes

```
pp
```

Sandwich is comprised of opcodes. The first letter of each line is the opcode, and the rest of the line is the arguments.

The opcode for this code is `p`, which means `print`. The arguments are also `p`, which is passed to the opcode.

The result of this code is that it prints out `p`, AKA ASCII 112.

Since the code is 2 bytes long, simply using the same two characters will give the average of the entire code segment.

Answer (score 2):

## [Plumber](https://github.com/Radvylf/plumber), 191 bytes

```
[]
]
]
...88 more ']'...
]
]
][[=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7RvbbuI49J2v8PIwShZISbgUDZtW8zAPO9LOrrSPblaTJYGmCgGFpNNqhm/v2o5zdxybQluqTSsI9sm5n@PjS@7se3u3CL1tNLifPS3jYBF5mwBs/Xj9r7LYOG4f2OFqp4IfHYCuezsEceBFO2AC3KvtfG/hKnofDHRV2219L1IubsLrm@DnTXixUrW1vVVcH5hXwPW10N36NgK/gP/AG8u0LlZ90AVdVdvazufAUf6wo1tt4Xo@ekTz3WAV3YILYKjgV2BQyLUdLW6VC@2H3jf2iAD4@RNAS50T7hIe8eW7EVjbD4hLwi2i7MSIsGIvFn3EiYoZItQQUNpIKap9MKT48JVKm@ApibPYBAs7UjRNC9zv4FMY2o8KJjooINOWnu8rXYB4VynWPYPXACsZUYHWvNwer1FrahYFQamFJ/HlLYESPW7dzRIbCpgm6O6i0AtWXbUEh6/QjeIwwHDUVN2uWhXJcf/aeEH0KVKGqor0du@GO1cpKARfrr9zCeWvyE3cUPN2vweRu3JDwmEjYYh6rTqmRvBhAXif31Jd4a@cQW25CT/byDcSWYhCtW28uyX2ideoPbNAAQmBK9oFe/gq9Bzcl1k1MT416TyD28TRNo4KZsONtu/du0WjPfTBY9FqJIZSj4IPFnwsiEnIo07MQrUPK3yFlIL@wS/I0EHs@9j/V1BntBmMthGjbcxom5TayvakxonC2C2zBrvQ6qIwtSD@NMk9NMk9abHIPUzura6lecHCjx13p8Qq@PABkZ2eiCyD1OUhpJSYxBeigdWU/ECkKMqZLErauLRRDFAXTL6QKwMFh7@HPGE4R1@/EYegHogaer2iRxFn8ay6yyKGyl5bwh73wV1C4I4SQEgyGndlGiQXZl7rWfCuEsn0edSOAwJiHVh9IPZdQYV1TVVtFlRd1XvhByz8QL5Vz0A5d0lSSOiqdbqy7iRKKhWVQdLDbA@xE1FpkAAVzZfx0tjGpuNBjdhQ@075Lvl0NgWSsg5YemYl61aE7TTnMTyrKfex8OQ6vULDOLM71xIaqXWiqSE1FaWgzpkPpvQT6nWYfQPX@om41jOudS7X@kFcGxJcl7wD89cqQ4/KYGQyGFwZjINkGL2IDKNMhhFXhpGEDNUgfXZUomR/UGByc75I5K4SoeGKRNlmq6hMIJ0C6TwggwIZPKARBRo1A@UDjAUKIweAXZ6PZPFvYpU47tILXKdYgDE6jKaOUb2j2eHSgthDFkRjUK9rzVu5ZBcijHzW6/GQ6cLI9HZkhjAyox3ZSBjZqAnZPp/J0KG35A7WebjD4KjuMBgc0R34yCTdgY9M0h1YyGruYLUlBFEJMPQdf3BPeJsKjYdyEifEqxmfP8Ql3FwKjmxJXib1bfPgxwGpx6FY6J1E8cNWxesvqHi9pSBtVbwupfj63Fbc/VlrDLw4vKT1kP5ybgVPKNDh1m4P@npmsk4uiVTQNOWH91rVlpYo@JYQWGBreL4RB1lvmghaMzVVEmxk1Tu0A2ezVlSksKE2AdfZMuDHFO@8ER1zxZZNK2PcTBm/zvj@mNJsyG17gRiQqt1fyAwcHOWZbIqt15T/6hPHlBj3EaomcTZGUtZqIX6oLeUK77dqy4G8LQevacvBaWx5puaTNN2rme0EJrPOJXsO5UymH9lkOXn9tU1mykUZrxDPy7hx69xnIox1lmGdiFa10DyaTLOTyDSVl8kUCi3@POmNiGIdzzzSMh1ZFAjf5xhVmZHlqU99du6rzFIPGLhOMnKdS7HBUl/b4HCauuNtGJKxczPmLeZgLhq63@OyAiwuxFnF8w1m6bBDW0qeHnnNJ2U@2YWeZK40bU3jl6deR8tYIxuz44y1S@4S6rRwXiU90kdihB5tVNXGbcR0KGMhuBRBIF/UTV9Lie32nUmwlkJfmW0Ol5yxS7mYcU05Y1pidpAl4PkE1jtTPDzHEHhWHpEvat6C8z1P5Hd72mXMVMpYRClpiVN9eNL2MEt/ZeGwUnaRHdVOJveBw1IE7xxyEabxIDN7o6TDOc6Q7RvkledAJ0XnlF321pcdSxVTCzEHhbchhLi0J2pWjpoWdkuLS9gWaKM/FhPKLBd7DWdegVXZCuHTnojJXVqTb7Ge4mCwsYo/lTixI0KB8tg1wFYcssnxUNbPye3n7HCXSBFHSRNCqUIkXVRq/uaao1JGt003m8c@PHkliUDBp4fwENfHVhOdx0oMKvUJZ51uy9xXaEL7LJbIayJUO9fJKyUkwSKPHegt3AnthqZXjrpF5I58z7MnMcWJDOe4hcx05SCHvUqOwRf8ZID9ZHKIf8oXflyHpYwc12GPweP/HizjwZKF6B58v/V8F7kxHlaWXuAoiuv3wYNKX5jLmx5JE3n7K3nlK3vdjA5nyYRq3tl3tqEXRMqXv//8qiXv6nnLRyV55fLbE7Q6Z/sHofn0rQ8tLPrTfw)

Drops a packet down, which is incremented up to 92 and printed. 92 is the ASCII value for `\`.

Answer (score 1):

## perl -Mfeature=say, 6 bytes

```
say"P"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIpQOn//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V901ITS0qLUm2BUgA)

I wrote a small program to find the program above:

```
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl

use 5.028;

use strict;
use warnings;
no  warnings 'syntax';

use experimental 'signatures';
use experimental 'lexical_subs';

for my $c (32 .. 127) {
    my $char = chr $c;
    my $s = qq [say"$char"];
    my $score = 0;
    $score += ord $_ for split // => $s;
    $score = int (.5 + $score / length ($s));
    if ($score == $c) {
        say $s;
    }
}

__END__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7RaoQwFETf8xXDIqgs6NYiLUj61L72B0oJqc1qIBvdJFKl7LfbRHelhd6nO2fmJtMLo8p5HqxAmR2Kx4qQsFtnZO2qZf/iRkvd2IroDptCbCft@BhfL8TYCyNPwjPlPdlo7gYjbFz9YysxyporZoePECDHzuA0IaqR3BfIMtwVDym@CfwsvOUGFHVr/F5t2Hp2PuPN8mm3ZHbvv8y6M8IHDiu66j1FZz4RMYQ/ba@kQ56DPvnAnyCF1A5JVmJ/QzmU0I1rkUQ2Tde0PAa1XlBf7tY6jK@1vXohF0IYe3l9ZmyefwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 6 bytes

```
echo Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I18h8v9/AA)

```
echo Z
```

[works as well](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I18h6v9/AA).

Just like my Perl solution, this was found using a brute force search.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 15 bytes

```
BEGIN{print"X"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6oCgzr0QpQqn2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 1 byte

```
3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M///3/j/fwA)

After the code cycles, **`3`** tries to output itself. However, **`3`** is an unnamed command, so it can't be directly outputted. Instead, it gets turned into `73`, which is outputted. `7` specifies the output format as "the same as the input", so the `3` after it prints `3`.

A more interesting solution:

## [7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 3 bytes (8 characters)

```
01116743
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M///38DQ0NDM3MT4/38A)

This outputs `3` as a number.

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 8 bytes

```
8a9m7a1o
```

Short and sweet. Verify the average character [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P@/RaJlrnmiYT4A).

**Explanation**

```
8a9m7a # Set the register to a value of 79
1o     # Output once
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ([Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)), 16 bytes

```
console.log('U')
```

Here's how I brute-forced the solution:

```js
const average = str => String.fromCharCode([...str]
  .reduce((total, char) => (total += char
    .charCodeAt(0)) || total, 0) / str.length);

for (let i = 0; i < 2 ** 16; i++) {
  const char = String.fromCharCode(i);
  const avg = average(`console.log('${char}')`);
  char == avg && console.log({ code: i, char, avg });
  // { i: 85, char: 'U', avg: 'U' }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [99](https://github.com/TryItOnline/99), 22 bytes

```
99 99 9
99 99 9
9 99
9m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##s7T8/9/SUgGEuOA0kOICigMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [T-SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/sql-server), 8 bytes

```
PRINT'D'
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f75a43419846d01941fa05f33aa24faa)

Answer (score 1):

## SimpleTemplate, 10 bytes

This is a simple code that outputs the average character itself:

```
{@echo"X"}
```

The average was calculated previously using JavaScript:

```js
var code = '{@echo"X"}';

var sum = code.split('').reduce((a,_)=>a+_.charCodeAt(0), 0);

document.body.innerHTML += String.fromCharCode(sum/code.length);
```

To get the right character, I just used a random one, until I got one where the result was the same (in this case, `"X"`).

The rules don't specify that the character can't be pre-calculated before. They only specify that you can't read the source code or that you can't take any input.

---

### SimpleTemplate, 1 byte

Just simply outputs the character average:

```
1
```

This generates a PHP echo (example below):

```
echo (<<<'DATA6229934543895a3c69912b6e6658160198d45280523b34711abdc124745'
1
DATA6229934543895a3c69912b6e6658160198d45280523b34711abdc124745
);
```

---

---

You can try both versions on: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/36449dad6c5de136ae489bcbeaddd97a6a7124bc

You can change the line 1048 to test the desired code.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 23 bytes

```
fn main(){print!("Q");}
```

Used modified [Perl answer's script](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207268/7773).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 11 bytes

```
print('K')#
```

The average value is 75.09, which rounds to 75 - <kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207329/92080 10 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 1 byte

```php
A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/f8f9/AA)

This will just output itself. Works with almost all of the printable ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace), 13 bytes

Outputs Data Link Escape (0x16)

I can't figure out how to put raw whitespace into a code block, so here you go:

```
[space][space][space][tab][space][tab][tab][space][lf]
[tab][lf]
[space][space]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgVOBk1OBi5NLQeH/fwA)

Explanation:

```
[space][space][space]           Push a number onto the stack
[tab][space][tab][tab][space]   Have that number be 22 (0x16)
[lf]                            End instruction
[tab][lf][space][space]         Output character from stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ada (GNAT)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnat/), 53 bytes

```
procedure GNAT.IO.F is begin Put("M"); end GNAT.IO.F;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJ1E3PSyz5/7@gKD85NaW0KFXB3c8xRM/TX89NIbNYISk1PTNPIaC0REPJV0nTWiE1LwWhwPr/fwA)

Why not?

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 15 bytes

```c
A(){return 84;}
```

Average is T. Returns ASCII code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/99RQ7O6KLWktChPwcLEuva/cmZeck5pSqqCTXFJSma@XoYdF1dmXolCbmJmnkZZfmaKJlc1lwIQFBQBhdM0lFSTY/KUdBSA5mhac9X@BwA)

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VwVFD09zov3JmXnJOaUqqgk1xSUpmvl6GHRdXZl6JQm5iZp5GWX5miiZXNZcCEBQUAYXTNJRUk2PylHRAujWtuWr/AwA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [C](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oLSkWEMpRUnTuvb/fwA) - 18 chars

```
main(){puts("S");}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 10 bytes

```
print("N")
```

[Online demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/5iaXaa4tRoquY8bLpySl4w)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 3 bytes

```powershell
+$A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X1vF8f9/AA)

`(43+36+65)/3 == 144/3 == 48 == ASCII('0')`

Answer (score 1):

## [bitch](https://github.com/Helen0903/bitch), 2 bytes

```
/1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSc74/1/f8P9/AA) or [verify the average](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P@/viEA).

Following up my [COW answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207345/92901) with one in bitch . . . read nothing into that. Outputs `0` (average 48 exactly). `/` outputs the accumulator value (initialised to zero); `1` is a no-op here.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 5 bytes

```
||'R'
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoAgFAX3/xQvN32hLlDR0gN0AwnFoCTMaJGd3XT5HjMT7itm63HozbPES0A0V@ScUru0GZAjfUSFqPekZrYDlKTHmWAKrMqqYj9jdTpQDZxh83H3DYv3Ex0syxrJPw), [Verify](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P9/TY16kDoA)

Straightforward solution, just a closure that implements `Fn() -> char`.

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP v1.1](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 6 bytes

```
33W/:.
```

I tried a different approach from Dion's answer.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/?code=33W%2F%3A.&input=), [Verify](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P@/sXG4vpUeAA)

Comment: I think something is wrong with the "Try it!" link...

Comment: @Dion decided to port the website over to https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP, so all try it links are broken. Here's a proper link: https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=33W%2F%3A.&input=

Answer (score 1):

## 1+ (with NOP), 3 bytes

```
'1:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVVbb5tIFH7nV5zYD0CDuTip2mXjh6ZSo11FVpS2DxVl0RjGNSrM0JkhF@32t7tnwBhsx@5aFprLd75zP1M9qxVn0/V6DCulKhl6XkVEWjwr8kQLV9XlohBuykuv4lJ5b9/4b1@/CS4vgj@8nCkqKkHxO1lyMQkmOZtUDZ9hjM@8WgpvkTOPsgfYHI8hOIeBHK7hrru6a/TCJ60YPPibClrqLXNg6geXiLjNU8pSCrmE9@/h@svk4zu4dH0Ef3h3C4F7gaub@We4ubt9uDDysuJCgXyWxlLwElJeFDRVOWcSNncZ/VFTw5AOyAxm7dayHfj3p2FkdAmc0aqopSURO4M5bu3QAPzlS2AcuYVq95uzgjIL9blEfHuw4WwG0/5a/yqBzsPosyTfaAgjOIcOHfkx7kYQLfOCguKwoECfaFormsWjHRItQp9yZQV2r5tVaCCvBvqjIHbAFGYPEuQRQQh1BSWZtSPtpgWXdHNGC4nmtXB0sTlrPqvSgXsHFlI5cO3AHO@jWIfL6WPn478BY01AqjOMRDtRSmE2A9Myd2NzDeczCHaOUI9LKnQqs@b2IYN9wDDZZ7iPNEfFK8uOdQZ3LpHoGq7A32UZ5OmvckEKghWXwUKQ9DtV8mx0AN7mY/qCjWMTCMtQD278EAP4gkPz3vPGpLPZ0Kb/Zcu@Dc1n7kBa6sLFlHwgmNPm9HGlK2yOjutqxdzYvS6uqwiPonk8dEWXOjKF@9HTcPQxMEOQnV@DomxLqcedD3GyzYpugXZ1XO7VS3Kvfi832pGLJkF8HOs1WMEVUfSUD1@/DoGTE8h/GiB9Ulp7tDHW6aw@YcrV0Gxfx7nz@Wq70h0KJ5SPkUN356rsNMdHse5QH1lIC@tN10WCY6FWlsnwDaAixH6zTwTbGbJwkQ0Z0hXBklUtCU66EzQh0rQVv7H7KPJPrRDLXqqM18p9FDkmpGZ5uhJdkZzQE6F02xyfRE2PwvaHVDNGFeu6BKs3CO@xW2IXX02V68fFMv8z7QMhpEQ5nMlodBbppR/riaRX0/gAvn14tthDSp3f@2Gn7hufmbANptEDcLYfaeR4G5R@XAwGFAKThJGSJomGj5KkJDlLklHL19lsr9dmEK7dJvkuhuQX)
[Verify!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P@/uqEVAA)

## 1+ (without NOP), 4 bytes

```
11+:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVVbj5s4FH7nV5xJHoCGcMnMql128tCp1GpXo2g02z6sKEUOOA1asFnbzEVtf3t6DCGQZJJtFCFfvvOd@3H1rNaczTabMayVqmToeRURafGsyBMtXFWXy0K4KS@9ikvlvXntv/ntdXB1Gfzu5UxRUQmK3@mKi2kwzdm0avgMY3zh1VJ4y5x5lD3A9ngMwQQGcriGu@7qrtELH7Vi8OAvKmipt8yBmR9cIeI2TylLKeQS3r2Dm3@mf7@FK9dH8Pu3txC4l7j6sPgEH@5uHy6NvKy4UCCfpbESvISUFwVNVc6ZhO1dRv@rqWFIB2QG83Zr2Q58@2EYGV0BZ7QqamlJxM5hgVs7NAB/@QoYR26h2v32rKDMQn0uEV8fbLiYw6y/1r9KoPMw@iTJVxrCCCbQoSM/xt0IolVeUFAclhToE01rRbN4tEeiRehTrqzA7nWzCg3k1UB/FMQOmMLsQYI8IgihrqAks/ak3bTgkm7PaCHRvBaOLjZnzWddOnDvwFIqB24cWOB9FOtwOX3sfPw3YKwJSHWGkWgvSinM52Ba5n5sbmAyh2DvCPW4pEKnMmthHzPYRwzTQ4b7SHNUvLLsWGdw7xKJbuAa/H2WQZ7@LJekIFhxGSwFSf@lSl6MjsC7fMxesHFsAmEZ6sGNH2IAX3Bo0XvemHQxH9r0S7Yc2tB8Fg6kpS5cTMl7gjltTh/XusIW6LiuVsyN3eviuorwKFrEQ1d0qSNTeBg9DUcfAzME2fk1KMq2lHrcZIiTbVZ0C7Sr03KvXpJ79f9yoz25aBrEp7FegxVcEUXP@fD58xA4PYP80gDpk9Lao62xTmf1GVOuh2b7Os6dz9e7le5QOKN8jBy6O9dlpzk@iXWH@shSWlhvui4SHAu1skyGbwAVIfabfSbYzpCFi2zIkK4JlqxqSXDSnaEJkaat@K3dJ5F/aIVY9lJlvFbuo8gxITXL07XoiuSMngil2@b4KGp6EnY4pJoxqljXJVi9QXiP3RK7@GqqXD8ulvndtI@EkBLlcCaj0Vmkl36sJ5JezeIj@O7h2WGPKXV@74edemh8ZsIumEYPwNl@opHjXVD6cTEYUAhMEkZKmiQaPkqSkuQsSUYtX2ezvdkEwSTcuE32XYzJTw)
[Verify!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P@/oaG2FQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 4 bytes

```
I[Wq
```

Characters are `73 91 87 113`. Average is `91`, which is `[`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
0
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=0&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Any digit works.

Or, if you think that doesn't count,

```
\\
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5C%5C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

`\` is a single-character string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
7
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=7&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Somehow the average of this program turns out to be the luckiest number in universe

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 5 bytes

```sh
<<< 5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGwfT/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 3 bytes

```
`TH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/PyHE4/9/AA) and [Check the average character.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P9/QogHAA)

```
`T   Escape the char T and push its charcode to stack
  H  Print all values on the stack and halt
```

Found by making the template `` `<any char>H `` and repeating the average calculator until it converges.

Answer (score 0):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 8 bytes

I feel that this is too boring to find...

```
"Y"print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//18pUqmgKDOv5P9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 4 bytes

```
" o;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0kh3/r/fwA)

Outputs `;` using a looping string literal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 2 bytes

```
"!
```

ASCII value of " is 34, and ASCII value of ! is 33.

```
(33 + 34) / 2 = 33.5 = 33
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X0n5/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 1 byte

```
e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/9f9/AA)

Haha. I'm not gonna be late to the party!

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 8 bytes

```
"Y"print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeikJmvYP1fKVIJzPv/HwA)

[This actually works...................](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBViEzr6C0REOTqyS/JDEHyC8uzdXIL0rRSNZUSMsvUkgGKlAo1uQqKMrMK9FIzijSANEGeqYK2gpgLfo5qXkaxZpA8P@/UqQSWB0A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 4 bytes

```ruby
p 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/n6tAwfj/fwA)

Adding a leading newline to lower the average from capital-letter land to digit land.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rexx (Regina)](http://www.rexx.org/), 5 bytes

```
SAY C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0qtqPj/P9gxUsH5/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB/Octave, 4 bytes

```matlab
''''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f9fHQj@/wcA)
Outputs single `'` character. And basically it's the way to write that as an immidiate value - the outer apostrofes are to indicate the value is char array so we're left with `''` which is escape code for a single apostrofe.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 2 bytes

```
51
```

For once, there isn't some overly long Excel function to get in the way.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 9 bytes

```julia
print(:W)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69Ewypc8/9/AA)

also works with

`:d|>print` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/3yqlxq6gKDOv5P9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
"DṘs+ĊmĊ"DṘs+ĊmĊ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWO5RcHu6cUax9pCv3SBcye0lxUnIxVBFMMQA)

##### Explanation

```python
"DṘs+ĊmĊ"DṘs+ĊmĊ  # Full program
"DṘs+ĊmĊ"         # String literal
         DṘ       # Duplicate and push the representation
           s+     # Prepend this to the original string
             Ċ    # Convert to charcodes (using Thunno 2 encoding)
              m   # Take the mean of this list
               Ċ  # Convert it back to a character (using Thunno 2 encoding)
```

Alternative (but boring) answers:

- **1 byte**: `0` (or any other number)
- **2 bytes:**  `''` (a character literal)